# Help reduce rubbernecking

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface, usability, live-refresh

Often users are forced into excessively looking back at posts to check if anything has changed.

Many times, we as users will have multiple tabs open in a browser. While some of the tabs may be older posts, it is often that a handful are both recent and of interest.

In order to monitor the progress of the recent and interesting tabs that are open, it is usually required to click on them every so often, and scroll all the way through to look for updates.

Each tab for each question already has a socket open (for reputation changes in the topbar, new comment loading, new answer loading, edit loading, etc.).

Each time a new event is received in the socket, if the tab is not focused, the title should be modified to include a number indicating the amount of changes. Chat and the active questions page already does this so the code for this feature already exists.

Events which trigger the +1 would be an **added answer**, an **added comment**, or an **post-edit**.

Upon inspection, I believe events which could trigger the +1 could be handled here, inside of one of the callbacks from the event emitter in StackExchange.realtime in the full.js script. It would be possible to add the callback inside of relevant `case` blocks, or perhaps in the `l(t)`, `y(t)`, or `S(t)` functions. Sorry for the minified code, this was all I have access to as an outsider :P

```
function s(e, t) {
    var n = e + "-question-" + t;
    a(n), U.addListener(n, function(e) {
        var t = $.parseJSON(e);
        if (t.acctid != StackExchange.options.user.accountId) switch (t.a) {
            case "score":
                m(t);
                break;
            case "comment-add":
                l(t);
                break;
            case "answer-add":
                y(t);
                break;
            case "accept":
                c(t);
                break;
            case "unaccept":
                c(t, !0);
                break;
            case "post-edit":
                S(t)
        }
    })
}
```

Here is what it could look like

[image]

Comment: Great suggestion. Another would be to use desktop alerts as well for those that don't have 2-4 monitors/browser open all the time.

Comment: Similar to @RyanTernier, just some method to 'watch' a question, since bookmarking doesn't provide much in the way of updates.

Comment: @Ryan I've used that idea in my [userscript](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260525/260841) :)

Answer (score 12):

I've used [@RyanTernier's](https://github.com/shu8/SE_Notifications/blob/master/SENotifications.user.js) idea of have desktop alerts and made a userscript to do this.

### [SE Notifications](http://shu8.github.io/SE_Notifications/)

This userscript will make HTML5 notifications popup when *something* happens on a question that you have open in a different tab. This is useful for keeping track of events without having to keep going back to see whether a new comment has been added, or an edit has been made.

It triggers a notification on:

- new answers
- score changes
- new comments
- edits
- new inbox notifications
- accepts/unaccepts

To use, you'll need a browser that support Web Sockets and HTML5 Notifications. For more info, see my [Github site](http://shu8.github.io/SE_Notifications/) to find out how to install.

I've also made a post at [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/q/6460/26088).

This is what would appear if you had this question open before I answered:

> [image]