# What privilege should 30k users get?

Tags: feature-request, privileges

The last time we [lifted the level cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253668/help-us-identify-micro-privileges-for-top-users/253669#253669) was in 2015. In 2014, we added a [unilateral close-as-duplicate power](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/1438) for gold tag badge holders, but no new reputation level. So we've been thinking about giving users more reasons to [keep playing](http://venturebeat.com/2013/02/07/borderlands-2-level-cap-increase/). (I've answered this question with some circumstantial evidence that people do begin losing enthusiasm after they hit 10k.)

Please answer with a description of the privilege you think would be worthy of 30k and include your arguments after a horizontal line (`\n---\n`). These should be on-site unlockables and not [physical items](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/what-happens-when-you-reach-200k-reputation/). Proposals don't necessarily have to give users extra powers on the site, but they should feel significant to those who have achieved this impressive level of reputation.

I left an answer to be an example. I've had a significant head start over most everyone else thinking about this feature, so please don't worry that your idea is underbaked. That said, the most useful answers will include justifications more than "wouldn't it be cool if . . ."

Finally, let me be the first to point out how odd it is that I am proposing a new [extrinsic motivation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93343/1438). It turns out that one of the great pleasures of this job is that I can do a small part in helping *many other people* enjoy writing great posts. I believe that a well-considered additional privilege level will benefit many users across the network. This is doubly true if that privilege empowers more people to solve problems and fix annoyances they come across.

Comment: [Can we allow 7.5K users  to suggest tag synonyms without a score of 5 in the tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103211/can-we-allow-7-5k-users-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-a-score-of-5-in-the-tag?rq=1) ?

Comment: None. 30k users are no better at moderating than 20k users. In fact I've seen way to many who don't even know the basics of SE principals. New moderator privileges should be rewarded based on moderation experience rather than reputation as reputation does not correlate much with ability to moderate, especially at higher rep levels.

Comment: I agree with @bjb568 - look at flag history above 20k.  If a user has thousands of accepted flags and less than 1% denied, then they are a candidate for significantly expanded moderation powers.  Reputation is only good for telling us the user has contrbuted good content to the community - it isn't as helpful past a certain point at telling us whether that user should be given more access to sensitive moderation duties.  It's clear, though, that more moderation must be performed by the community.

Comment: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3251136#3251136

Comment: Older dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101772/need-new-30k-abilities

Comment: @bjb568: As I mention in the question, these need not be extra powers as long as they feel significant. Some of the more interesting ideas [last time around](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69989/propose-a-new-20k-reputation-privilege) are purely informational or cosmetic. Please feel free to suggest less disruptive suggestions than my comment moderation answer.

Comment: @AdamDavis: I didn't even check for dupes. Sorry about that. We started talking about this internally last month and it slowly dawned on me that we aren't in the best position to come up with good ideas. I should have known that the idea to ask on meta wasn't even original.

Comment: @JonEricson No need to apologize! It's old and at the time there was no need for it.

Comment: When will the decision be finalized? And, when will we get to see the feature?

Comment: Custom question filters based on all sorts of things.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 6-8 weeks

Comment: @Jon While this got many answers, I think if you want more this better become [tag:featured], this way it will also attract users from different sites around the network. (not just MSE dwellers :-))

Comment: The real question is: what privilege or superpower will [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) get when he reaches one million reputation points?

Comment: @Konamiman Looking at his badge count also makes me curious about whether or not there would be special privileges for badges...

Comment: How about 30K users, on any site, can opt-in for alerts when questions like this are posed on MSE?  This Q is 8 months old and I'm just now seeing it. :(

Comment: @AwesomePoodles Wouldn't the Hot Network Questions sidebar do the trick?

Comment: @Mureinik, not reliably, no.

Comment: A free T-shirt has 30K StackOverFlow on it!

Comment: Why stop at 30k - why not plan out 50k, 75k, 100k, etc...?

Comment: How about a game-like approach with a prestige function: Their score resets, but all their votes are from then on worth 1 more. :P

Comment: A year later: anything happening with these ideas?

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Not at the moment. :-( Unfortunately, Documentation and a few other features have soaked up a lot of developer time since the fall. Even shortly after posted this, I switched to asking about [lightweight features](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253668/1438). I'm looking forward to the summer when some of the projects will be getting wrapped up.

Comment: @JonEricson - A secret hat would be nice!

Comment: So... Now that documentation's dead, can we get a status update on that thingi, please?

Comment: @DavidArenburg: I'm going to be bringing this up internally, but it might be a while before we can update the status. It's not on the roadmap yet.

Comment: @JonEricson now, another year later, has there been any more progress on this?

Comment: @publicstaticvoidmain: Nope! And I think it will be a good long time before we can get back to it. For better or worse, there are more pressing issues right now and for the foreseeable future.

Comment: It's useless to leave this open for over three years with no prospect of action being taken. It should just be historically locked at this point.

Answer (score 151):

### Your own personal blog attached to your profile

- Write articles on topics that interest you
- Others can discuss your articles in attached chatrooms, over which you retain full ownership + the ability to promote insightful chat messages to a featured position below your articles.
- The nature of the content is up to the author, but must still abide by the usual content policies (on topic, no rudeness, no plagiarism).
- Readers can vote on articles (up/down) and highly-voted articles will be featured on a separate section of the site.
- High-tech XML-based "feed" allows folks with special software to "follow" individual users' posts and pretend it's 1999 all over again.

---

Everyone's kinda fixated on *moderation* privileges here. That's understandable, but... I'm not sure it really makes a lot of sense: community-moderation works by *distributing the load* of moderation across a sizeable population, and 30K is a pretty high bar - even on Stack Overflow, there just aren't a lot of them to carry any significant weight.

But at 30K, there's a pretty good chance you can *write*. I mean, that's usually how you *get* 30K. So, why not offer folks who've gotten that far another outlet for their talents?

Comment: Of course, this would be a *wonderful* link in with Careers.

Comment: Part of me is kinda afraid people will use this for all kinds of soapboxing, especially if blog content does not have to be tied to site content (and even then, I can see cases where this could go horribly wrong, even with the assumption that users with 30k should be "above" such things.)

Comment: **Thanks for diverting focus away from moderation privileges** - you're highly on point there - but I don't think I can get behind the blog idea as a 30K privilege. If nothing else, it's gonna be a heck of a time investment to build something like that *and* do it right. Now, that isn't a reason not to do it, but assuming we do build that, 30K then seems like a really steep requirement for entry.

Comment: Well the topic is privileges, and not moderation, so I find this on topic. I also like the idea proposed, and would probably use it on Stack Overflow if it were available. I believe this would be a constructive way to essentially post canonical information without the hoops of the main site.

Comment: What a fantastic idea for the site.. but not for 30k users. I think that would be a real shame not allowing such a thing for the many *great* users who are not even close to that rep. You'd also possibly entice *spammy SEO nutters* doing all kinds to get to 30k to spam their sites, so would need to be only to users with *really* good activity. e.g. X% good to bad review ratio, good up to down vote ratio on their answers/questions, etc.

Comment: Rather than that make SE revert their awful decision to stop supporting any new site-wide blogs at all just because some of the existing ones didn't spit out content on a daily basis.

Comment: That'd be easier to sell if "moar wordpress" wasn't part of the deal, @Christian. Regardless, that's a separate discussion.

Comment: If we built this *and* folks actually used it *and* it wasn't a complete trainwreck, I'd tend to agree @Anna... But, it's always possible to *lower* the rep level for a privilege, and we've had good success with this in the past. 30K is a pretty high bar for something that more than anything else just needs a lot of warm bodies, but it's pretty low for "can write, has stuff to write about".

Comment: @Shog9 Granted, but if the end game is "try to get this right and then lower the access barrier", then what you're really suggesting is a limited roll-out pilot-type feature rather than a privilege. Precedent or no, we'd be right back where we are now, looking for a replacement for a 30k-level privilege and making folks feel like something that's theirs is being taken away otherwise.

Comment: When you say the "usual content policies", does that include the CC-by-SA license?  Posts on the Q&A site that can be edited by anybody feel different to me than blog posts, and I wonder if a different flavor of CC, one that takes a firmer hand with derivative works, would be more appealing to prospective bloggers.

Comment: I think CC-BY-SA strikes a good balance, @Monica. Note that it doesn't necessarily imply in-place editing, but allows the author to retain ownership while giving others some confidence that they can reference, reuse and extend useful posts without the fear of having the rug pulled out from under them.

Comment: I was playing with the thought of starting something blog-like on stuff that was too opinion-based or otherwise unsuitable for SE anyway, so I like this idea. However: How will this feature be adapted to public betas? If the reputation threshold is also 30 k, it will be quite difficult to reach. If the threshold is different and lower (say, 10 k), this may have disallow people continuing their blog, if a site graduates.

Comment: @ChristianRau: I have very little experience with the site-based blogs, but can’t we combine the two: Every site automatically gets a blog and every 30 k user can write on it?

Comment: I don't know that that's really an *end-game*, @Anna - I think it'd be a damn good privilege for 30K users, which is why I suggested it. All I'm saying is, if we *did* build this and it turned out to be wildly successful then... Well, that'd be a pretty good problem to have - and I've little doubt we could find a way to get more return on the dev-time investment without taking away from 30K users. Think, suggested edits - we opened up a privilege to anyone on the 'Net without really taking away from the folks who'd earned that privilege, and first we solved a whole lot of problems with it.

Comment: "Everyone's kinda fixated on moderation privileges here."  As you said, understandable -- everything you get after 1000 rep is a moderation privilege (the two "milestones" are really mod privs).  If this is a concern, it might apply to lower privilege levels too.

Comment: Exactly, @Monica - high rep users should be trusted with more and more power in exceptional situations, just like mods. Let's get away from this, "congratulations! You did such a great job on the cathedral ceiling frescos we've set aside some time for you to spend mopping the floors in the latrine!"

Comment: Sounds good to me @shog9 and I think I like the blog idea.  Just saying we might want to look again at some of the lower levels too.

Comment: I'm almost at 30k on two different sites… and I've participated in a few blogoverflow blogs. I'm not sure this would be any more successful than blogoverflow; why wouldn't I just link to my own blog (if I had one) in my profile?

Comment: @Shog9 Are you SURE you want this feature implemented? I now have 10k on a beta (which, according to most of the other answers here, would correspond to 30k on a graduated site). You can imagine what my SE blog would be like, right? You'd probably get a mention, you know.

Comment: Already popping popcorn, @rand

Comment: @James It would be pretty hard for an SEO nutter to get to 30k in the first place. That takes at least 150 days of reputation-farming...

Comment: As a 30K+ user who doesn't blog - this is probably a feature I'd use, it doesn't sound like a lot of work - great idea.

Comment: FWIW, community/site blogs could (automatically?) draw from posts by their users then.

Comment: @AshleyNunn They might, but there's an easy way to avoid being drawn into their soapboxing: Just don't read their blog.

Comment: Is "moar wordpress" still part of the deal after the changes to the SE blog?

Comment: Would a single-user team page cover this (at least for Stack Overflow)?  (Also, I imagine a 30k SOer could set up their own blog if they wanted...)

Comment: I'm currently maintaining a small one of my own out of my own pocket. To get one from SE, with the content box & formatting we're used to as well as imgur for hosting images, would be a great reward for reaching 30k.

Comment: Despite Quora has blogs even for users with 0 upvotes, that is a nice idea.

Answer (score 135):

**Please consider this an example proposal.** There are a lot of potential pitfalls with comment moderation, so I don't want people to get *too excited* about this particular idea. It occurs to me that since we really want to hear *your* ideas, seeding the question was a mistake.

## Comment moderation

At 30k on graduated sites (and 10k on beta sites) grant users the following powers:

1. Access to the comment flag queue
2. Delete comments
3. Purge comments (i.e., one click to remove all comments on a post)
4. Move comments to chat
5. Access to deleted comments on the post page via a menu option
6. Undelete comments
7. Access to comment edit history
8. Edit comments
9. Convert to comment

---

I'm suggesting these privileges because comments are one of the few things that elected and appointed diamond moderators can do something about that the rest of the community cannot. Other than flagging, there's no way for regular users to fix problems with the comments on a post. Having a powerful privilege to aspire to provides a better incentive than providing somewhat less-powerful privileges. Anecdotally, people most look forward to the [10k privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) which introduces the final piece of community moderation: post deletion.

I estimated enthusiasm following a privilege level by doing a longitudinal study of median time-to-next-action. Looking at the 868 Stack Overflow users with more than 20k whose accounts were created after 2010-10-05 (the date [privilege notifications were first issued](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/membership-has-its-privileges/)), we can see how quickly they posted and edited after gaining each new privilege:

| rep_level | level | median_next_post | median_next_edit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | participate in meta | 13 hours | 70 hours |
| 10 | remove new user restrictions | 11 | 63 |
| 15 | vote up | 8 | 53 |
| 20 | talk in chat | 8 | 48 |
| 50 | comment everywhere | 6 | 33 |
| 75 | set bounties | 6 | 26 |
| 100 | edit community wiki | 5 | 25 |
| 125 | vote down | 5 | 23 |
| 250 | view close votes | 4 | 19 |
| 500 | access review queues* | 2 | 3 |
| 1000 | established user | 3 | 13 |
| 1500 | create tags | 5 | 13 |
| 2000 | edit questions and answers | 4 | 8 |
| 2500 | create tag synonyms | 3 | 8 |
| 3000 | cast close and reopen votes | 4 | 6 |
| 5000 | approve tag wiki edits | 4 | 6 |
| 10000 | access to moderator tools | 6 | 5 |
| 15000 | protect questions | 9 | 12 |
| 20000 | trusted user | 10 | 15 |

<sub><sup>*</sup> The access to First Post and Late Answer review queues is an outlier because it was [introduced around August, 2013](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/08/podcast-51-the-return-of-codinghorror/). It’s a good guess that most of these users got notified of their new privilege when they had far more than 500 reputation.</sub>

These are exceptional users, so they participate (as a group) far more than others. If we look at users with more than 5 reputation, the median first post after getting [participate on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) is 215 hours. Compared to their later behavior, trusted users start slow. Notice that they also slow down again after hitting 10k or so. Critically, the slow down after 10k also occurs for 30k users (N=429), so it’s not just an artifact of the cutoff.

There’s circumstantial evidence that increasing the top privilege level increased participation at higher levels. More to the point, the relatively underpowered [15k](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) and [20k](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) levels appear to be less effective at motivating users than 10k powers. So introducing something really helpful, such as comment moderation, seems in order.

---

**However**, I think comment moderation is mostly a waste of time. I'd much rather let [the system handle comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204402/hide-trivial-comments). Unfortunately, there are already *so many* comments that should have been edits (or even answers) instead that we can't blindly hide/delete old comments. Creating this privilege will mean committing to manual comment moderation for the foreseeable future. Comment moderation is tedious and unrewarding so I'd rather have our top users do something more productive with their time.

Therefore, while this is my best idea for a new privilege level, I'd really rather find something else. Please consider answering with your own idea and/or upvoting better answers.

Comment: I like the idea of adding comment moderation but some of the items listed, I'd be worried about including: access to deleted comments, undeleting comments, editing comments. I'd think that we'd want these privileges restricted to a small # of users and on SO 30k user base is pretty large. Would users have access to all comments in the flag queue? There are things that moderators need to be aware of and if we no longer see these flags, then we lose the ability to step in. There might be repeated not-constructive/rude comments that needs messaging - that'd be lost if handled elsewhere.

Comment: If editing comments past 5 min is allowed, it definitely should be disabled on metas. And even so, there are enough bitter 30K users around willing to use this feature to make others look stupid. I imagine these new powers being used for harm more often than for good.

Comment: @bluefeet: I agree. I've spent the last couple of weeks trying to split out a subset comment moderation tools that would be good for giving to 30k users and I can't come up with a reasonable set. Removing the informational features leaves people without the information to make good decisions. Removing the action features mostly exposes people to junk. That's why I'd prefer to develop an aging system for comments instead.

Comment: @pizza: If we gave more people comment edit powers, we'd also need to give more people access to comment revision history. (Currently we don't show that to _anyone_, so this would be a big step in itself.) Like I imply in the answer, this is my best proposal and I wouldn't vote for it myself.

Comment: @bluefeet Comments were never meant to be a first class feature, holding important content.  At any time users know their comments can be deleted for many reasons much more trivial than reasons behind editing, removing answers, etc.  Further, if deleted questions and answers can be viewed by 10k users, surely the comments aren't any more sensitive or important to require significant elevation.

Comment: Just because we have a history of treating comments as special doesn't mean we need to or should continue that history.

Comment: @JonEricson Creating even a comment flag queue would be a step in the right direction IMO.  It's really easy to throw _too chatty_ flags at a flag queue for users to review - we get tons of those and they are a waste of time for moderators, even obsolete comment flags. But I'd hesitate to send in rude/offensive or not-constructive flags.

Comment: @AdamDavis There are comments that are posted that no-one should see...ever!  I personally wouldn't want to have a large # of users have the ability to see those.

Comment: @bluefeet Is that really different than questions and answers?  Questions and answers have been posted which no one should see as well.  If there are comments that, if seen by *very* trusted users, would significantly damage Stack Exchange, then we need to take a very hard look at why that is and fix it.  Comments that can tear apart the fabric of the universe seem like an exaggeration.

Comment: @bluefeet I see how it is; you're currently constructing a new horror movie/website/game/something based on deleted SO comments and you don't want anyone to scoop you.

Comment: Shhhh @Servy don't give away my secrets!

Comment: @ bluefeet: Separating out chatty and obsolete comment flags and letting the community  (whether 30k or some other level) clear them is a great idea. If you have a moment, would you mind writing that suggestion up?

Comment: @AdamDavis - With questions and answers containing sensitive information (credentials, medical records, etc.) or credible physical threats against other people (yes, this happens), we know to contact SE employees and have this stuff burned. With comments, we operated under the assumption that only moderators would see these, and have not asked SE employees to purge these from the database. These would all now be exposed to normal users not bound by the moderator agreement, and we have no way of searching back through the history of them.

Comment: I could get behind 30k+ users having the ability to moderate comments, but I'd limit the comments they can review to those flagged as "not constructive" or "obsolete". I would prefer to have only moderators handle the "rude or offensive" or "other" comment flags, because these tend to show more severe patterns of behavior and may require moderator intervention. The latter two categories are also far less common than the former.

Comment: @BradLarson Which only suggests that we don't need to treat comments as important or vital.  How about we don't allow viewing deleted comments (except by moderators, as we have now) but we do allow deleting comments?

Comment: @AdamDavis That leaves the problem of abusive 30k users deleting comments just because they say things that they disagree with, or to troll users.  If other users can see the deleted comments, such abuse can be discovered.  If only a small handful of mods can see it, it's much more likely for it to go unnoticed.

Comment: @Servy perhaps, but the current system just ensures abuse the opposite direction. By keeping comments a protected form of communication which requires moderator intervention we find that it's easy for everyone to heap abuse on people. It doesn't even have to be big forms of abuse, but the type of minor sniping that drives new users away. Comments should not be held in such high regard, nor be closed to normal user moderation systems. They should be ephemeral, easily deleted minor bits of clarification. If a user has something important to say, they should be encouraged to add an answer.

Comment: While I like the idea of more people helping get rid of unnecessary comments I don't think 30k rep privs is the right thing for it for reasons you stated including "we want these users to be answering not doing easy, unfulfilling comment moderation".  A comment review queue should be created, and anyone should be able to flag comments that will end up going into this new queue, and people with > 500 rep (or maybe even 5000 rep) will be able to review the comments and take actions from there. This will take the majority of comment moderation away from mods, except the "requires mod attention".

Comment: @AdamDavis And yet it's not appropriate to create a new answer to say, "Mr. Smith's answer is incorrect and doesn't work because of Foo."  That should be a comment.  But if Mr. Smith can just delete all of the comments that explain why their answer doesn't work, that would be bad.

Comment: As a moderator who has dealt with patterns of less than desirable comments going undetected for lengthy periods with only a few moderators deleting periodic bad comments, I don't really want people other than the moderators to be able to _also_ delete comments. It's hard enough to coordinate "oh user X has done what with comments?" and the appropriate mod responses with only a few of us. It feels like a forensic study because of how poorly the SE interface handles comment flags already, this would make it impossible.

Comment: @BradLarson the rude and offensive flags are already more likely to be handled by the community than the other comment flags. They tend to get a stronger reaction and are more likely to contain any of the single-vote delete trigger words. What we need is a tool that makes mods aware of users that get unusually many comments removed because they're offensive. The community should be able to remove those, it just shouldn't leave mods in the dark.

Comment: The ability to delete comments unilaterally feels a little creepy. It seems like certain users would be able to silently censor others. If deletion and undeletion were removed from this, I think it would greatly reduce the ability for it to be abused.

Comment: I think there's a nugget of something useful here, but I don't see it as being very effective at handling flags - rather, there's some decent potential here for letting high-rep users anticipate problems and avoid situations where flags are necessary at all by shunting unproductive conversations into chat and doing a bit of gardening on unruly exchanges. Though, perhaps Hans would be less frustrated with comments on his answers if he knew David would be seeing the flags rather than a moderator... Heck, perhaps the real value here would be in simply making flags *visible* to high-rep users.

Comment: @TravisJ So maybe instead of a unilateral delete, there should be a voting system for comment deletes like there is for trusted users deleting questions and answers.

Comment: @JonEricson: Why are you posting the next-action statistics here and not in your question?

Comment: @Roombatron5000 we (anyone) can already delete comments via flags. What is lacking is the ability/visibility for people to cast pile on flags that allows the community to handle it (like spam flags do on posts) without needing to involve mods.

Comment: I apologize if I'm repeating stuff here but I don't really have time to read all these comments. I would *love* a better comment moderation system and I really like what [shog outlined here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252844) but I think a lot of the ideas outlined in this post are *really bad*. I can only imagine the chaos that would ensue if users could unilaterally  delete or undelete comments. I certainly don't want to be here when that happens. It's been said many many times that comments are supposed to be ephemeral and require little moderation.

Comment: I know that's what your end goal is here but I do not believe that is what will happen. Allowing anyone to edit a comment is also a bad idea. We just said comments aren't supposed to have a lot of weight and now we're allowing users to edit them whenever? For what reason? This would also require implementing comment revision history and that would require moderation to prevent abuse.. wait, I thought the whole idea was to spend *less* time moderating comments? I can see so much abuse coming from this and, as a result, so much more moderation time it's not even funny.

Comment: I really like the idea of making comment moderation better. I do not like the idea of making it an (essential) free for all. All of this was said with [so] in mind. I readily admit it might be ok on smaller sites, but I still do not like the implications. We're giving a random group of people practically full control over comments (even more power than moderators currently have).

Comment: Editing comments is one of the sneakiest things you can do on the site, because there's no accountability and no notification.  It's good that only moderators can do that -- and I've seen even *that* cause problems, so I sure don't want to increase the number of people who can do that.  I also don't think we want non-mods to be able to undelete comments.  You once argued that comments are kipple and people shouldn't get attached to them; bringing them back from the dead by anything other than mod action seems inconsistent with that.

Comment: After considering this for a few days, I like the viewing parts more than the moderation parts. I think *it would be nice to be able to view deleted comments and see comment edit history* (this would be a strong motivator alone in my opinion). The unilateral deletion and purging is still hard to get behind, but perhaps with oversight in the form of voting (re: answer deletion votes) it could also be useful.

Comment: I'll take "see deleted comments"; anything more is gravy.  It's kinda handy to have when you participate in Metas, you might also see something that should be brought to mods attentions, and ... well, damnit, there's often so much juicy drama in deleted comments. Its so hard to find good stuff to read while eating popcorn...

Comment: @Won't That juicy drama would be one primary reason I *wouldn't* want deleted comments to be shown to anyone.

Comment: @JoeZ. look, you may be anti-drama, but I need something to read while I eat popcorn.  Don't poop on my popcorn, bro.

Comment: I would rather a comment flag queue be unlocked once someone has done xxxx useful comment flags, with less then yy bad comment flags.

Comment: As a mod I'd really like to get help with comment moderation and when it only cuts out the chatty and obsolete ones, that would be fine. I like the idea of a review queue about that. I also think it should be capped how many of those reviews can be done. Editing comments is not a good idea - sometimes I think we mods should not be able to do that, especially when we don't see who edited what and when.

Comment: I'm actually [giving away all my rep above 25K](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14783/is-there-a-limit-on-how-much-rep-i-can-give-away) because the next level (100K) is too far away! *Any chance higher then a snowflake in hell this is ever going to be implemented?*  ***Please?  Pretty please???***  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby: Yes, there is a chance for some 30k and above privileges. But probably not this one, unfortunately. This is a controversial idea internally that we are unlikely to get agreement on. I do plan on going through the existing suggestions and proposing one (or a small group) for implementation, but there's no timetable for that.

Comment: How about this one for 50K users (in the worst case: #4 all by itself) and another one at 75 K?  That would allow even more gamification and finally: advertise that at 100K you get a T-shirt and a mug??? Then you would *actually have a roadmap to 100K!* **;-)**

Comment: There! 15% of my total rep over to you.  At the next meeting, ask your fellow colleagues how many bounties they got awarded for their feature requests!  **:P  ;-)**

Comment: For those who like this suggestion: see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213691/create-flagged-comments-review-queue) meta post.

Comment: 30,000 isn't very numerically significant compared to 32,768

Comment: The one problem I see with this is that users can instantly delete an answer by converting it to a comment and then deleting that. Maybe if they can just *vote* to convert an answer to a comment, that would be better.

Comment: Related (well-received) feature request from 2012: ["_Make comment flagging work more like chat flagging, available to users with 10k reputation_"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138149/997587). Others by Pekka in 2013: ["_Make community comment moderation a more public process_"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213694/997587) and ["_Create "flagged comments" review queue_"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213691/997587).

Answer (score 105):

#### Allow 30k (beta 10k) users to see deleted posts directly from a user's profile, and/or to optionally include it in search results.

Viewing deleted posts from the profile was [proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222640/allow-20k-users-to-see-deleted-posts-from-other-users-profiles-particularly-for) in the past for 10k or 20k users, but people said that that would be too many people looking at stuff someone deleted. 30k is a smaller amount of people, so it might make more sense to give it to them.

Including it in the search results would be in the same vein, i think. Perhaps a user remembers a certain deleted post and wants to find it using search.
To avoid flooding search results with all the deleted stuff, it would only be included by a `deleted:yes` flag in the search.

---

In fact, the link might be redundant if we add search. You could just do `user:12345 deleted:yes` to get their deleted posts.

---

[mattdm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/154627/mattdm) gave a great example use-case in a comment that i'll copy here:

> An example I can think of: a post looks suspiciously spammy, but it's kind of on the edge. I look to see if the user has a pattern of such questions, and maybe see one half-decent post with a few upvotes -- it'd be nice to be able to see if they've got previously-deleted low-quality posts or not.

Comment: Would you like to extend your answer to describe what the value or benefit of this is?  Does it benefit the site, and if so, how?

Comment: Better moderation tools?

Comment: I don't follow you yet.  Can you elaborate on how seeing deleted posts in someone's profile (or being able to search for deleted posts) enables me to do a better job of moderation?  For instance, maybe you can outline a couple of example scenarios?

Comment: That would be great. There're lots of useful and fun deleted posts on SO, so being able to search for them would be awesome. Couldn't care less about viewing deleted posts of specific users though.

Comment: An example I can think of: a post looks suspiciously spammy, but it's kind of on the edge. I look to see if the user has a pattern of such questions, and maybe see one half-decent post with a few upvotes -- it'd be nice to be able to see if they've got previously-deleted low-quality posts or not.

Comment: @mattdm Great example, i've added to the post.

Comment: Also, I do an extensive amount of plagiarism hunting on SO. Sometimes I see an answer that looks very suspect (e.g. a mysterious number from nowhere that was probably a copied score, or "I really liked so-an-so's answer, but..." when that user is nowhere to be seen, or uncharacteristically good grammar). It would be nice if I could at least ask another user if they could try to find it for me.

Answer (score 93):

### Comment on (recently) (self) deleted posts

I've occasionally had the situation where I'm trying to explain something to a new user about the site - new post review or just habitual refresh of the front page newest, or watching the chat room feed.

My comment is about how the question doesn't fit, or how it can be improved, or something of that sort. And I click 'Add Comment' and a red error box pops up that I can't comment on deleted or locked posts.  I refresh the page... two down votes, a close vote, and yep, its got a pink background.

> deleted by user54321 15 seconds ago

Well. Thats not useful at all. I am shut down on my attempt to try to help out the user. They don't have any other posts on the site and at this point the most I could do would be bother a mod to leave a comment there.

So, there's my proposal.  For posts deleted less than ${some time} ago, let 30k users still make a comment on the post. This might be as little as an hour or as much as a day. Its meant to allow 30k users to provide guidance about the site to posts that have been recently deleted so that the user would have a better chance of having the next post be one that fits within the scope.

Comment: With a ping, same as for moderator comments posted within an hour of deletion.  (I would make the limit an hour, same as that case.)

Comment: I think this can be added for 10k or 20k privilege, with Monica's restriction. I think there is no reason this should be 30k.

Comment: I'd want this for any deleted post, but it's a good start.

Comment: @Won't it could be read as "Comment on deleted posts" or "Comment on self deleted posts" or "Comment on recently deleted posts" or "Comment on recently self deleted posts" - any of those variations. Just a question of how restrictive to make it.

Comment: Alternatively, make it easy to open a chat with that user.

Comment: I've had a few (admittedly rare, but significant enough to stick in my memory) instances where user A posts a question, and user B, who doesn't see the merit of the question, posts a comment that leads A to frustratedly delete the question while I'm still writing my answer. It's always bugged me that in this situation, SO's policy of not being able to contact users out of the blue prevents me from communicating with A *or* B about the matter.

Answer (score 90):

### Expedited on-hold & reopen actions

At 30k (10k beta), grant the following privileges:

- Instantly put a question on hold for any reason *other* than duplicate, provided that:

  - The question has not been previously closed and reopened.
  - The question, if in the review queue, does not have pending "leave open" votes.
  - (Maybe - open for discussion): the question is on the front page or, failing the ability to implement that, "new" (definition TBD).
- Instantly reopen a question that was put on hold by a 30k user, provided that:

  - The question has been edited since it was put on hold.

---

We have the dupe-hammer specifically for *duplicates*, and tying it to reputation on specific tags makes sense.  We need the expertise (and site experience) of specific users, not any old user with a certain rep total, to handle those.

The *other* close reasons -- off-topic, too broad, opinion-based, and unclear -- do not usually require such expertise.  If you have 30k rep on a site you should have a pretty good idea of what's answerable and in-scope and what's not.  When the decision is **not likely to be controversial**, we should empower high-rep users to act quickly, before too many answers start showing up.

Just as we want to put problem questions on hold quickly so they can be fixed, we *also* want to help them get reopened once the problem has been addressed.  So I'm proposing that the insta-hold be **reversible**; a question that was insta-held and then fixed should be insta-openable.  This insta-reopen does *not* apply to questions that were put on hold (or closed) through other means (community vote or moderator action).

One might argue that the reopen part is unnecessary; the community can take care of that, after all.  But on some sites we've seen new users (who don't necessarily understand Stack Exchange) get upset when their (salvagable) questions are put on hold and then it takes a while to get them reopened.  Let's trust that our 30k users can tell when a question is no longer too broad (etc); enable them to get the question back on its feet so the asker can get answers, and if there *are* still problems with the question, the usual community actions are still available.

Comment: I don't think we want insta-migration, though, except maybe to your own meta.  I'm not sure what to do about that.

Comment: At the very least, I'd want to add a few more qualifications to this. For example, I don't think upvoted questions should be one-click closable. I might make it so that any voting member could override the one-click close vote with a single reopen vote, not just 30k users. Otherwise, I think this could turn into a disaster on a site like Stack Overflow where we have a number of 30k users that are... *aggressive* with their close votes.

Comment: Maybe this needs to be adjusted for some sites?  I participate on several smaller and medium-sized sites and our problem is getting questions put on hold before too many answers roll in.  With my proposal, at worst somebody can do this *once* per question, the community can override, and, well, somebody who consistently misuses site privileges after warnings can find he's lost them.

Comment: @BradLarson a "leave open" vote in review blocks this.  I've seen a *lot* of questions that ought to be closed nonetheless be upvoted (including, but not limited to, hot network questions), so I don't think a lone upvote should stop it.

Comment: I really don't notice a problem with people being too eager to put bad questions on hold (although maybe I'm just one of them) so I foresee a trivial amount of abuse at the most. It would however help so very much with keeping the site clean that even that little bit of possible abuse would be entirely offset against it. I do believe though that a gold badge should be required -- certain things like 'unclear', 'lacking information', etc often require some knowledge of the language to properly determine.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel a gold tag badge would make this completely useless on my sites.  We have very few people who even have the dupe-hammer.  Perhaps there are *other* badges that people should have first, but if so they should be general site-caretaking badges.  This is why I excluded duplicates; those *do* need the expertise in the particular area.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Perhaps you have some ideas on how well my suggestion for [***double-badger superpowers***](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254325/153355) would work — or fail to work — on smaller sites. Or is it possible that the need for such just does not arise on smaller sites?

Comment: Maybe a single "reopen" vote the reopen queue should then undo it, converting the close vote into a normal close vote.

Comment: @IanRingrose that seems reasonable (though a vote from the author probably shouldn't count here).

Comment: It might be good to have a score requirement too, like deleting answers. Negative score?

Comment: @Kevin closing is temporary and doesn't affect visibility, unlike deleting, so I don't think we need anything too strict here.  On some sites close-worthy questions get upvotes nonetheless, so I wouldn't want to hinder that.  But I could see the logic of a restriction like "score no higher than +5" or something in that ballpark, I guess.  Any threshold would need to be evaluated and possibly adjusted.

Answer (score 81):

### Expedited capability for migration *to* your site

At 30k on graduated sites (and 10k on beta sites) grant users the power to suggest migration in a more pro-active way to "their powerhouse".

Example: Say you have >30k rep on site X, but also associate with site Y where you have [not a lot of rep], provide some capability to migrate content from site Y to site X since you're well-equipped with the know-how of what goes/doesn't on site X.

---

I am a high-rep user on [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com), and *often* find questions on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) (SO) that is (La)TeX-specific. As such, I flag these questions, suggesting migration to TeX.SE since the fit is mostly perfect. It just makes sense to move the post to a *more* suited site.

However, since I'm a lower-rep user on SO, I can only flag a question and suggest TeX.SE as a better location (I assume it's treated similarly on the back-end to a vote-to-close). This flagged is effective < 5% of the time. I think the reason here is that the post ends up in the [Close Review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close), which is a particular problem on SO. From a TeX.SE point-of-view, SO almost seems like the garbage-collector of posts since it has so much coming its way, from all walks of life.

I don't see much benefit in leaving formerly on-topic posts on SO rather than migrating it to a site that is tailored to address those issues. This will naturally be the case as more proposals on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com) launch.

In short, if you have interest in a specific field of expertise (read: high-rep on a specific site), you should have a pretty good idea of what is on-topic on that particular site (read: you've hung around long enough to know what's going on) and therefore should know what fits on that site if it lands elsewhere on the network that you might troll on-and-off.

While my suggestion is based on an SO-TeX.SE relationship, it may hold in general. However, I wouldn't know how to address this speculation with some circumstantial evidence from [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com), say, mainly because there's no easy way to perform cross-network queries/analysis.

<sub>This proposal might be consideration for something like an "In-migration review queue" rather than granting "high-rep privileges on a low-rep associated site". This proposal might need some baking...</sub>

Comment: Interesting idea. Have you read [Respect the community – your own, and others’](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/)? It might help you refine your idea.

Comment: @JonEricson: Haven't, but will look into it, thanks. If this idea is beyond the 30K question scope, yet still interesting, I could migrate it to a full [meta-tag:feature-request].

Comment: Meh, I'm not sure I want users associated with a specific site to have actual power in migrating stuff *there*. That comes at the risk of migrating away perfectly on-topic stuff on the source site just because users would "rather like it" on "their powerhouse". Migration is just too heavy an action to leave it to the lower folks, especially ones who don't have much reputation *on the source site*.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Originally, almost everything computer-related seemed to be on-topic on [so]. Now though, there are over 100 child-sites on the SE network with far better specialization than what [so] can provide, since questions may end up being washed out in the diluted stream of posts. Over time and in general, many on-topic questions on a source site will become far-better suited for some target/child site, despite the fact that there's still some form of on-topic-ness on the source. Dilution is most likely inevitable, but this suggestion might help mitigate that. To each their own though.

Comment: I participated in a private beta that had some overlap with a graduated site.  So when anyone posted a question that fit the scope of the graduated site, a very senior member of that graduated site went and posted comments that say "This belongs on X.SE".  We don't want that at all.  The user chose the post the question on that site, so we should respect that unless it is off-topic on the original site.

Comment: @psubsee2003: The migration suggestions I've made have been between two graduated sites and mostly for users who don't know about the target site. And saying "The user chose [to] post the question on [some] site" doesn't mean they know what they're doing. While you may have been around a while, some posters are desperate, and things end up in the [so] post-mill. Specifically, (La)TeX-related questions not only _is_ a better fit on [tex.se], more comprehensive and often superior answers are given on that site than on [so].

Comment: @Werner you didn't mention graduated sites in your suggestion, hence my comment.  But I still don't agree on overriding the wishes of the original poster when the topic is on-topic in both locations.  When there could be a better site, you should suggest it via comment, not just arbitrarily decide to move it for them because **you** think it would be better,

Comment: @Werner and ultimately topic "turfing" isn't limited to beta sites.  What's to stop a 30K user from running through a site and moving everything related to their preferred site.  This needs a lot more restrictions.  (1) More than just a minimum rep on the current site (maybe 10K on site 1, 30K on site 2 .  (2) Only migrate when there are no upvoted answers and the questions is a week old (or more).

Comment: There's nothing wrong in enlightening a new user about other sites where he can post his questions. But a high-rep user *from* that other site just *voting* to move things over to the site *he* thinks it belongs is an *entirely* different thing. @psubsee2003 Ardesses the exact problem here. At least there should be *loads* of additional restrictions to such an ability, probably up to so much that you can just leave it to a mdoerator once it's closed anyway.

Comment: Being an expert in a prospective migration target doesn't make you an expert in the *other* site.  I'm very uncomfortable with sites being able to poach questions from other sites.  Maybe you should only be able to do this for questions closed (not on hold, but closed) as off-topic on the other site -- in other words, you can't poach questions that are ok there (or are new enough that they might be being fixed), but if another site has said "no", that'd be different.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: This is a good suggestion. I'll incorporate some of the said comments (others included) to refine my proposal.

Comment: Seems to me like before you get any sort of expedited migration power, you should have a large amount of rep on **BOTH** sites.  A question shouldn't be migrated away unless it is off-topic on the original site.  A question shouldn't be migrated to unless it is on-topic on the target site.  And a question shouldn't be migrated at all unless it's actually a good question.  Users with 200 rep on Site A and 30k rep on Site B wouldn't be a good judge of what should be migrated to or from Site A.  You need to be familiar with *both* sites!

Comment: Maybe add migration targets to sites you have >30k on, which (when picked) let other closevoters vote to migrate there? You couldn't cast your own closevote unless you already had 3k on the source site; if you don't, it'd flag.

Comment: I like this proposal if one caveat is added: A 30k user can suggest to migrate a Q&A from any other site. The author is notified and only if the author agrees, the Q&A is migrated.

Answer (score 62):

## Unlimited close votes

At 30k on graduated sites (and 10k on beta sites) grant users the following powers:

1. Unlimited close votes (like moderators currently have).
2. Unlimited reviews in the Close review queue.

The main way to keep the high quality of Stack Exchange is to fight the waves of low quality questions with close votes. Many users join this epic battle on daily basis, but they are limited to a meager 20/40 reviews and/or votes per day. At 30k we can assume they know what they're doing, and lift this limit.

<sub>**Disclaimer**: personally, I don't take part in the epic battle described above for reasons beyond the scope of this question. However, having such power would be a great incentive, if not to me, surely for others.</sub>

Comment: "*At 30K we can safely assume they know what they're doing*" I completely disagree. Rep does not now nor will it *ever* = "knowledge of moderating/the site", "good decision making", "careful attitude considering all parameters to make a good judgement" etc. That said, that's another issue, so +1 from me for your actual idea.

Comment: @James fair enough, still stick to my belief but removed the "safely". :-)

Comment: You know you are up for [a tough battle](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285438/we-need-more-close-votes/285486#comment152909_285486) to get this passed Shog9?

Comment: Very, very few people hit the current limits on a regular basis; not sure this is much of a privilege. Also, unlimited *non-binding* votes potentially just creates more work for other users. I'm pretty sympathetic to the desire to make close votes more *effective* for trusted users, but more weak opinions isn't likely to accomplish much.

Comment: @rene whoops, looks like you just Summoned him, lol... anyway missed that whole discussion there otherwise wouldn't have suggested it.

Comment: @Shog9 fair enough, wasn't aware of that. If it matters, I'm really for what Jon offered himself, comments moderation is cool. :-)

Comment: I would see this coupled with either/both % of times I used all my votes and/or % of votes cast that effectively lead a question to be closed.

Comment: Unlimited might be bad, but [***double-badger superpowers***](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254325/153355) just might work.

Answer (score 62):

## Realtime and smarter feeds

---

Many processes in Stack Exchange are cached, or have delays, that enable the higher performance of the site.

I propose that these caches are selectively removed for 30K users, and that feeds become personalized and more "real time". For example:

- Review Queue "icon" on the top bar does not count items you have skipped
- 'live' feeds of 'favourite' tags - tags you subscribe to.
- 'subscribe' to posts - get comment, answer, and edit notifications on 'favourite' questions.
- other... (feel free to edit with suggestions)

Many of these suggestions are items that, I presume, are hard to implement for performance reasons (caching normally is), but people with 30K have earned the "privilege" of a more personalized experience.

Comment: I loved this. A 30k user would have a priority access to the site. But, implementation can be tough.

Comment: I would *love*, love love **love** the ability to subscribe to a post. Good grief, I can't even begin to imagine how that would change some of the tedious stuff I have to do every day. Don't know about the rest of this, but that one'd be a winner in my book.

Comment: @Shog9 You could script it by periodically polling API methods [posts/revisions](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/252691/revisions?site=meta) and [posts/comments](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/252691/comments?order=desc&sort=creation&site=meta). Up to 100 posts being monitored at a given time, checked once every 30 minutes (2 API calls), still fits into 10000 requests quota. And posts from the same site (meta, meta.so) could be pooled into one request. (Also,  `/questions/{ids}/answers` for answers).

Comment: @Shog9 - I proposed a feature similar to subscribing to a post (provided that the tab was open) http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246404/178816

Comment: The "subscribe" option mentioned here has been implemented with the "follow" feature now.

Answer (score 58):

**Increase the weight of moderation action.**

- One spam or offensive flag counts for three
- One vote to close counts for three
- One vote to delete counts for two
- One upvote on a tag synonym counts for two (downvotes excluded because this immediately deletes the suggestion)

**Remove restrictions on moderation rate-limiting.**

- Remove a quantity-based flag limit, and introduce an hourly flag limit of, say, 20.
- Same as above for close votes, but instead set the limit higher on Stack Overflow.

---

For spam/offensive, these things aren't hard to tell, and this just saves time. For close votes, one 30k user and two <30k users, or two 30k users seems balanced. For deletion - deletion of content that should be deleted can take a while, and this expedites it. Same thing with tag synonyms.

w.r.t. restriction removal: 30k users who may be hitting the close limit on some sites could do better if they just came back to it in an hour and looked at some more questions. A rolling rate-limit seems effective.

Comment: Only 20 flags/hour?

Comment: @bjb It was sort of an arbitrary choice.

Comment: That seems lower than now since people usually only flag for 1 or 2 hours/day. 100 flags/hour seems more suitable.

Comment: @bjb568 [shrug], if SE considers this, it'll be debated enough internally to come to a reasonable value. The value I put here isn't too important.

Comment: Does anyone with 20k, or 10k, or even 3k, even have the slightest chance of capping their 100 flags/day? I have trouble spending more than 30 a day even going through all my reviews and bumming around for a few hours in new posts.

Comment: @Nathan Flags, not so much. Close votes, yes. The point is to allow effectively unlimited flags and votes, while still keeping a rate limit so it isn't abused terribly.

Comment: @Emrakul: Fair enough; perhaps you could reword to clarify the more important bit and mention specific cv rate limits.

Comment: @bjb how are you going to raise 100 flags per hour (i.e. one flag per 36 seconds)? This is absolutely impossible, unless you are explicitly searching for the posts to flag, which is discouraged (and even in this case it'd be pretty difficult).

Comment: @nicael Explicitly search for bad posts? Peh, just see the front page. If I didn't have 3k I could get thru 100 flags in 3 minutes just combing thru a tag page.

Comment: @bjb in this case, it's applicable only to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @nicael Yeah, I suppose, but SO also has a huge number of 30k users.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I don't know bout others, But I've spent 100 flags in 4 hrs. You get a lot of bad posts on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BhargavRao: Yes, I was speaking from an SO perspective at the time, and, if memory serves, spending 3-4 hours a day on moderation. I still have trouble imagining how anyone could hold up under the load of flagging so much, unless perhaps they were doing a dedicated tag cleanup. (That wouldn't likely be sustainable anyway for long.)

Comment: @Nathan, The [new answers to old questions](http://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions) tool for 10k, is a gold mine of flags. There are 25 pages. If we go through the 25 pages at once, it'll be easily 40-50 flags. (Get to 10k on ELL asap, You'll get to know that ;) ...). There are many other users who cap 100 flags almost everyday. It just needs patience imo. EDIT: Flagged 2 new NAAs even as I was writing this comment

Comment: @BhargavRao: Even when I *had* 2k privileges when ELL was in beta, and was spending more time in 2k tools than any two other users (OK, hyperbole), I didn't raise many flags at all. Nowhere near 100. (ELL gets much less traffic, obviously.)

Comment: True, SO gets a lot of traffic, We need more users who flag the posts though. :( .... As an aside @Nathan, You can always help us flag NAAs on Stackoverflow. A few others and myself have been working on an [app](http://stackapps.com/q/7049/42239) that helps to open up the new answers tool to <10k (which you have already seen). There are around 200 flags that are needed everyday, you can join us whenever you are free.

Answer (score 58):

### Trusted on meta.stackexchange.com

+1000 rep on meta.stackexhange.com

Users who have 30k+ reputation on a particular site surely know enough about the Stack Exchange system to fully participate on meta.stackexchange.com; why not carry over some of their rep, say, 1k over to meta.stackexchange.com?

This would be a reward similar to how after 200 rep on any site, you start at 100 rep on all sites, but it would only be applied to meta.stackexchange.com.

Maybe it'll even get more established users participating in this meta.

Answer (score 51):

### Ability to migrate a comment conversation to chat

Comment moderation has been touched on in [multiple](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252691/164200) [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252707/164200) so far, but I'm going to add one more.

I suggest that we give 30k users the ability to move comments to chat and purge the extended conversation in a single click.  We all know that extended discussions happen all the time - these could be to clarify the post, help another user understand an answer, debugging, or general off-topic/non-constructive comments.

While the standard notice appears asking users to move to chat when the discussion gets lengthy, it requires that all users must have the required [20 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) to participate.  If a  new user doesn't have that the rep, then a migration to chat is impossible and it continues to takes place in the comments.

Currently, moderators have the ability to [bypass the rep requirement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93444/provide-a-tool-for-moderators-to-migrate-comments-to-chat) and move comments to chat when we get a system generated "excessive comments flag".

I propose that 30k users have the same ability to migrate the comments to chat when needed. Users would have access to a link to move the comments and purge them from the post in a single action. This would give users the ability to help curb possible off-topic conversations that take away from the post and move it into the proper channel...chat.

Comment: It looks like this doesn't address the potential for abuse (such as pointed out [in this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252690/what-privilege-should-30k-users-get#comment825553_252707)).  Allowing a single user to wipe all the comments under a question, without requiring any confirmation from anyone else, even under their own answer, sounds like something that could be abused.  Do you have any thoughts on whether that will be a problem and/or any ways to mitigate the risk?

Comment: @D.W. the comments will be moved into chat and purged from the post. Since they are in chat, it is slightly different then deleting the comments because a user is irritated. Once the comments are moved, there is a link left pointing to the chat conversation.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realize it left a public link pointing to the chat conversation.  That makes sense -- thank you for the explanation.

Comment: This would require some sort of community generated comment otherwise this gives 30k users the ability to silently delete all comments (by deleting the notification comment).

Comment: This is definitely worthy of a 30k privilege.

Answer (score 49):

**Nothing.**

What differentiates a 20k and 30k user? Not much.

In comparison to 1-500, 1k-3k, 3k-10k, and 10k-20k, the difference from 20k-30k is pretty minimal. It is, frankly, not unexpected that 20k users will eventually reach 30k, and at that point, they either know how to use the site or they don't.

Adding a new reward tier for its own sake is a bad idea, particularly when we're already aware that it's not as though we'll trust 30k users significantly more.

Therefore, I'd like to suggest taking a couple of your favorite proposals from this list, and lumping them into the 20k privileges.

Comment: How will your suggestion to do nothing for 30k and instead lump the good suggestions into 20k do anything to address the perceived issue of enthusiasm drop-off — you know, the very thing which adding bright shiny POWAHS at 30k was hoping to fix by motivating people to keep on playing when they’d previously run out of shinies at 10k or 20k?

Comment: @tchrist Gamification for its own sake is misplaced.

Comment: @Emrakul It's not for its own sake when it comes with privileges deemed useful and which you would *"lump into the 20k privileges"* anyway.

Comment: @Christian I think my point may be unclear. I'm not saying "don't add privileges," I'm saying "don't make an arbitrary new tier for privileges; just add to the existing and entirely functional one."

Comment: @Emrakul I know. And I'm saying "add an arbitrary new tier, because it helps motivation *while* at the same time not being *just* for gamification alone".

Comment: Agreed. It is sort of demeaning to imagine users that would suddenly gain some new enthusiasm due to some minor toy they get at 30K. I recently reached 20K on SO, but I actually don't even know what new privileges I got and don't care about them. For many, I would guess participating in the site is an addictive behavior that is not really related to badges and awards and privileges.

Answer (score 41):

Grant 30k users (10k on betas) the following privileges on non-meta sites:

- If two users have flagged a comment as "too chatty", "obsolete", or "not constructive", and at least one of them is a 30k user,and no one has disputed the flag, delete that comment immediately.  (Exception: if a 30k user flags a comment under their own answer/question, then they are treated as a regular user for that flag: 30k users don't have the power of accelerated deletion on comments on their own post.)
- Add a review queue visible to 30k users that lets them view comments others have flagged as "too chatty", "obsolete", or "not constructive".  Obviously, the identity of the user who flagged the comment should not be displayed.

These privileges would only apply on non-meta sites.

---

This allows 30k users ability to help moderate / clean up some comments.

It does not sound especially prone to abuse.  We already advise people that comments are second-class citizens and might be deleted at any time.  As Adam Davis [wrote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/2915/adam-davis), comments should be for ephemeral, easily deleted minor bits of clarification.  If a user has something important to say, that should normally appear in a new answer or an edit to an existing question or answer.  So, if a comment occasionally gets deleted that shouldn't have been, this seems acceptable: the benefit of cleaning up noisy comments seems to outweigh the risks.

The exception for comments on the flagger's post is to prevent abuse (e.g., to prevent a 30k user from deleting a comment that is critical of their question/answer), as [suggested by Brad Larson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252690/what-privilege-should-30k-users-get/252707?noredirect=1#comment825553_252707).

Meta sites are different; disagreement and controversy is expected and useful there.  As a safeguard, meta sites would be exempted.

(This proposal may need careful thought and possibly further adjustments...  Feedback welcome.)

Answer (score 39):

It might be time to add more cross-site privileges. For example, if I have 30k on one site, I might be given the right to see deleted posts on all sites. Alternatively, I might get a higher flag weight on all sites.

Another option would be to let 30k users edit questions on any site. Answers are different since you need to know a bit about the subject to be able to edit an answer safely. Questions, on the other hand, tend to be easier to grok and most edits will be to improve clarity and/or grammar. So, if I have 30k on one site, I should be able to directly edit questions on any other site. Perhaps with some extra requirements: I must also have a copy-editor or at least Strunk & White badge on the 30k site and, for example, at least 500 rep on the target site.

Having 30k on any site suggests that a user is at least relatively well aware of the SE model. I think that 30k is a good threshold at which certain privileges can be transferred to accounts on other sites.

Comment: I often see 30k (and even 100k) rep users on Stack Overflow suggest poor migrations to other sites. While they may be familiar with *their* site, I really don't think they necessarily have a good handle on *all* sites, or even the norms of what is acceptable to have in a question or answer on another site  (pardon me while I go and edit out all the 'Hint's on Math.SE).

Comment: @MichaelT agreed. That's why I added a requirement to have at least 500 rep on the target site and did not mention migrations (though I did think of it). I've seen too much crap being migrated by well meaning but uninformed users.

Comment: Perhaps 1 site × 100k, or 2 sites × 50k, or 3 sites × 33k, or 4 sites × 25k, or 5 sites × 20k, or 10 sites × 10k?  :)  More seriously, the new gold Illuminator badge might be worthy of cross-site editing privs.

Comment: Alternative: allow edits on meta sites after you get 30k anywhere. Metas don't have suggested edits, and it becomes annoying to see grammatical or typographical errors that could be trivially fixed ... if you were on your meta.

Comment: @muru that's a great idea! Please post it as an answer so it can be upvoted.

Comment: @terdon posted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272089/270345

Answer (score 38):

### Fancy hats

I propose that 30K users should have access to a range of fancy hats, similar to those we saw during "hat week"

Comment: As much as I'd love a nice Montecristi, Jon did say "not physical items".

Comment: @Shog9 - Digital hats are not physical items. They're digital.

Comment: Also, can I have a nice SE hat? I missed out on all the "site bling" they posted out when Scifi:SE was setting up...

Comment: [Digital hats](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9ndSa.jpg)?

Comment: @Shog9 - With [new hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245170/winter-bash-2014-secret-hats), obviously...

Comment: [A *good* hat](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/videogamefanon/images/9/9a/Jumpman.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20131201115308).

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know why your network profile shows posts from your scifi account even though it's hidden?

Comment: @CDR - Not the foggiest. It's been mentioned to me a few times though.

Answer (score 33):

### Increased tag synonym privilege

Users with this privilege can suggest and vote on tag synonyms with lessened requirements; instead of [a score of 5](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms), they only need to have **either** a score of 1 (demonstrating involvement), or for the tag to be below a certain threshold of usage (demonstrating not-going-to-hurt-anything).

---

I often notice tags that ought to be synonyms of other tags, but I cannot make the suggestion because I do not have the requisite 5 score in the target tag, and very few other people would be around to vote on it at all, because the tag simply does not have that many questions (or does not have enough *rate* of questions to deliberately work towards the 5 score). This privilege would allow people to perform more cleanup of the long tail.

(That said, I'm not sure I want this to actually be the shiny new *30k privilege*, because I think it ought to be available much *sooner* than that.)

Answer (score 32):

### Kick questions off the Hot Network Questions list

(or at least vote to do that.)

Many Hot Network Questions are great, and they are great ways to funnel traffic to the better parts of a site and increase engagement.

Other Hot Network Questions, however, are not great. The mechanism is strongly biased towards junk-food, lowest-common-denominator questions, and it has a [terrible feedback loop](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286020/breaking-the-hnq-feedback-loop-on-bad-questions) that makes those issues self-reinforcing. For many 30k+ users, seeing those HNQs triggers an immediate reaction along the lines of

> this question does not represent the best of my site,

possibly accompanied by expletives that share an acronym with the French Federation of Speleology.

Allow us to make that explicit in ways that count: allow us to (vote to) remove questions from that list. If, say, five 30k+ users from a smallish site vote that way, then that's a strong indicator that the question's presence of that list is probably grating to a significant fraction of the committed userbase.

Comment: Most sites don't *have* five 30k+ users, or if they do, most of them are mods.  Game Design has three non-mods.  Astronomy has two.  Economics has zero.  If you want to make this viable, it needs to require at most two votes.

Answer (score 30):

#### More Close Votes

#### Increased Review Queue Limits

---

This is similar to, but different than [Shadow Wizard's proposal for unlimited close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252703/194162)

Some of my logic for this request is echoed [in this post on Meta.Programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6507/provide-10k-users-more-close-votes).

The TL;DR version is that community members who are active in community moderation will frequently run out of close votes on a daily basis.  Likewise, they'll be prevented from using the review queues after they hit 20 reviews.

Having more close votes means low quality questions can be closed in a more timely basis which provides important feedback about the question to the person asking the question.  Poor questions that linger can attract less than helpful answers, and they give a negative impression of the site to other visitors.

If you search the [The Whiteboard's chat history](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=&user=&room=21) for phrases like "out of close votes" or "need more close votes" you'll see that it is a frequent issue for the review queue regulars.

Shadow's proposal calls for unlimited close votes whereas my proposal only calls for an increase in close votes.  Please note that I'd take unlimited close votes over have no increase at all, but I'm not certain that *unlimited* votes is necessarily the next logical step.

Comment: One can increase the power of close votes without increasing their number under [the double-badger superpower proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254325/153355).

Answer (score 25):

#### Ability to ping two or more users in a single comment

If the reason it's limited to one ping per comment is to prevent abuse, then surely such *trusted* users should not be subject to that rule.

It would be a small yet sometimes genuinely useful tool imo. Not that I'd get to use it for a while.

Comment: I like this idea, but maybe it should be linked to the user's comment history (frequently highly-upvoted comments, low flags, high number of accepted comment flags) rather than rep, which isn't even tied to comments.

Comment: @Zibbobz that sounds a lot more complex. Privileges are only based on rep AFAIK, so you're talking about a whole new system. I'm just suggesting something that could work with the current system, the same way other non-rep-related privileges work. Not to say your suggestion wouldn't be better, but unlikely to be implemented mostly due to the cost vs the opportunity.

Comment: I like this idea, but it has a major drawback: The mentions causing the pinging will be visible for everyone and lower-rep users will be confused why it doesn't work for their own comments once they've seen them. It's not intuitive that (multi-)pinging ability could be related to rep or comment history.

Comment: @das-g I see where you're coming from, though bear in mind there are many facets of stack exchange that share the same predicament. This would be as much a part of the discovery process as anything else. Additionally, it would be extremely easy to detect a second @ mention via js and show a tooltip which could lead to the privelege page, thereby adding another channel for induction.

Answer (score 25):

### Immediately protect questions having 3 or more answers.

10K users can vote delete questions two days after these are closed. Users with twice as much rep, at 20K, gain privilege to vote *immediately* if closed question has score -3 or less.

15K users can protect questions a day after these are posted. Similar to elevated delete vote privileges, system could grant users with twice as much rep, at 30K, a privilege to protect *immediately* if question has 3 or more answers (possibly including deleted ones).

Comment: inspired by [Allow 15k rep to protect highly viewed young questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268353/165773)

Answer (score 23):

Guaranteed evaluation to `status-*` tag for open [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s at respective per site meta in one or two months.

---

Users having substantial experience of access to ([almost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136020/165773)) full privileges after 20K are likely to be interested in features worth considering.

Attention to their requests would show that Stack Exchange [listens to their community](https://blog.codinghorror.com/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do/).

---

Requirement for request to stay open to be eligible is primarily in order to prevent temptation of reposting prior popular requests to "force" their evaluation. (Reopening of incorrectly closed or clarified question should probably reset the "evaluation timer".)

Also, to keep system stable:

- there should be some kind of [rate limiting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/rate-limiting/info), something like one (or two, or four) eligible requests a year
- eligible questions should have feature-request tag from the very beginning, to avoid complications related to retagging, in a way similar to how it is done for [dupehammer](/questions/tagged/dupehammer).

Comment: attentive readers may notice sort of [escape hatch](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?EscapeHatch) here, in the form of migration from per-site meta to MSE. This... "feature" is expected to be used judiciously, assuming an appropriate scrutiny of such migrations by source and target meta communitites

Comment: related: [Meta escalation/response process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347959/165773)

Answer (score 23):

### Expedited Reopen for questions on hold as unclear

At 30k on graduated sites (and 10k on beta sites) grant users the ability to immediately reopen questions which:

1. are on hold as unclear (but not yet closed)
2. have been edited by the original question asker

---

This is a limited form of the [suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252698/154627) from @MonicaCellio. On Photo-SE, we get a lot of vague questions where more information really is needed to provide good answers, and recently we've been putting them on hold very quickly (which is good, because it prevents the question from accumulating a bunch of guesses at what the possible question might be as answers). But, we're a little slower at reopening these when the clarification *is* provided, leading to a period of frustration. This would allow high-rep users to end that frustration quickly.

(I wouldn't suggest this as the *sole* 30k privilege, but maybe one of several.)

Comment: I'm afraid that this sounds to me like requiring every homeowner in town to carry a shotgun because you saw a coyote on your block. I'm not sure that reopening is a problem on other sites, and more importantly, since you've been able to fix the closure problem socially, you should be able to do the same with this.

Comment: @Josh I'm not sure I'm seeing the analogy. What does the coyote represent, and where are the required shotguns?

Comment: The coyote on your block is the problem of slow reopenings you have on Photography; the shotgun is the extreme power that every 30k user anywhere on the network gets.

Comment: Well, yes, that's obviously the parallel you draw, but I'm still not seeing how these things are *like* a coyote on the block or *like* a shotgun in any meaningful way.

Comment: I think this is an excessive power given to too many people based on a minor, localized, problem (that has a better solution anyways).

Comment: Maybe this should be immediately reopen AND answer, with the answer being required.

Answer (score 21):

If a 30k user votes to close a question, and another 30k user has already voted to close the question, then the question immediately gets closed.

If a 30k user votes to reopen a question, and another 30k user has already voted to reopen the question, then the question immediately gets reopened.

This will be the policy for all questions that have a score of 0 or less, except those questions that have already had at least 1 close history *and* at least 1 reopen history.

Comment: Maybe also give this to anyone that has a silver tag badge that matches the tags the question was asked with.

Answer (score 20):

#### Give 150 rep (instead of 100) on site association

While +50 rep on top of the current 100 site association bonus doesn't seem like much, it ultimately gives 30k users:

1. The [downvote privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).
   The choice of 150 allows for 25 downvotes on answers (at -1 rep per answer), which is enough for those that may infrequently visit/lurk another site, who can already vote up, flag and comment.
2. More leeway for [bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).
   With the minimum bounty being 50 reputation, users can place 1 bounty on an associated site without re-entering new-user privilege restriction territory (< 100).

In terms of how much a 30k user would 'know a site' before accessing more dangerous privileges: a base association of 150 is also still 100 rep away from [viewing close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) on their own question, and 350 from [accessing review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) - which is still a large amount of reputation to earn on a site to access those privileges, especially with no large 'bank' of questions/answers bringing in regular rep (as would be the case on their 30k site).

Answer (score 19):

**Edit questions and answers without bumping them to the front page**

This one may be more appropriate for Silver Tag Badge holders, but I'm going to throw it on the floor here anyway.

---

One issue that comes up on some of the SE sites I participate in is that when someone is doing a wave of clean-up edits, all of the questions and answers that they edit count as recent activity and those questions get bumped to the front page, thus drowning out other, more relevant, recent activity.

At 30k it's assumed that you're a well-behaved member of the community.  You're not going to go on a destructive rampage.  If you're the kind of person who would do that, you would have been caught long before you hit 30k.

This privilege grants you the ability to participate more in site maintenance, by editing questions and answers to recategorize, correct changed terminology, improve formatting, or other cleanup tasks which help improve site content.

This privilege is strictly opt-in - you must explicitly select to not bump an edited question.  At 30k you are trusted to make the correct judgement.

In all cases the OP recieves a notification of the edit and may roll back if they feel that the edit materially changes their intent.

Comment: I think I would want to find some way to notify moderators, at least.  It'd be pretty easy for a rage-quitter to do a lot of damage this way (by picking on users who aren't around much).  You wouldn't want one flag per edit if the idea is to do clean-ups, but *some* sort of notice would be important. Can you think of a way to address this (without flooding mods)?

Comment: @MonicaCellio - something like a once per day (it could be once per week, I'm not religious about this) notification then recent activity in your user profile could be reviewed if it's felt necessary?  Sound about right?

Comment: Reviewing recent activity works if there's some reason to look. Mods need to be told "hey you might want to look". Maybe a daily flag per user notifying of ninja editing?

Comment: @MonicaCellio - a perhaps more palatable alternative is that this class of edit always goes through the same Review Queue process that lower-rep users get, so at least it gets vetted by the community (and the burden of reviewing the edits - and rejecting or flagging them if objectionable - gets more reasonably spread).

Comment: But if the reason you want this is cleanups, isn't that just going to flood the reviewers?

Comment: @MonicaCellio - true, but in general terms there are a lot more reviewers than mods so I'm not sure that it would be too onerous.

Comment: I am not quite sure about this idea when it comes to content edits, but it would be a nice thing to have for tag edits.

Comment: No! You're reasoning as if the only purpose of bumping edited posts was for review. But when it comes to tag edits, there's a much more important reason which has nothing to do with the editor. Tag-changing edits must bump the thread in order to reach readers. Otherwise people who subscribe or more generally are interested in one of the added tags, or who ignore one of the removed tags, will miss the question.

Comment: @Gilles - no, that's not what I'm reasoning.  Tag edits could perfectly well stay as they are.

Comment: @DarthMelkor If I may ask, why did you leave SFF.SE? We miss you! :-) The undisputed king of LotR, with unfailingly great answers - there's been a spate of LotR questions recently too - and already #5 in terms of rep ...

Comment: @randal'thor - other people will have to give the answer to that one, I'm done with it and have no desire to rake over it again.

Comment: I would rather see an unbump - if a 3.5k user is fixing typos from 5 years ago, I would like to be able to agree that the rest of us don't all need to see this question on the front page.

Answer (score 18):

This might require too much special casing to be realistic, but I think something like it is worth proposing. It falls somewhere in between moderation and the content maintenance [that Uphill Luge was talking about in his deleted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252740/).

**Let 30k users administer wiki-locked questions and curate their pages.**

This might include:

- Applying a wiki answer lock to a question closed as "not constructive", "too broad", or (on SO) "recommendation" (possibly and older than *D* and with at least *N* score) (This could require voting, like deletion, rather than being unilateral.)
- Converting a historical lock to a wiki answer lock (not a likely feature)
- Editing a *question* that has a wiki answer lock, not just the answers.
- Commenting despite the lock; deleting and editing others' comments
- Deleting/undeleting answers regardless of score

The simplified version of this would be **let 30k users ignore wiki answer locks**: they can act on the question and answers as they normally would.

---

The idea here is to let users who are clearly great at creating good stuff work on some of the most potentially useful, but also controversial and usually messy, stuff on their site, to help bring it up to snuff. Generally someone with this rep level has a certain sense of ownership of a tag or set of tags, and wiki-locked questions can be important assets for a tag.

This isn't something that moderators are able to do -- limitations of time and subject proficiency mean that it's most sensible for them to apply the lock, prune the answers, and then just stand back for other users to do the editing. Allowing high-rep users to handle the whole affair takes moderators out of a loop they maybe don't need to be in, and the abuse potential is low since the power is so narrow.

Problems with this include the fact that I may be looking at this through a Stack Overflow lens. Wiki-answer locks are fairly rare, and I'm not sure this is even relevant for sites outside the Trilogy; they may just not have posts that warrant the lock.

For SO at least, though, this might help alleviate the rarity -- with more people able to meaningfully interact with those locked posts, it makes more sense to apply the locks widely.

Comment: What do you mean by a "wiki answer lock"?  I know about Community Wiki (everybody can edit), and I know about locks (nobody can do anything, including vote), but what is a wiki answer lock?

Comment: This thing: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182572/ @MonicaCellio. It may indeed be too SO-specific, as I feared.

Comment: Oh, interesting idea.  Looks to be SO-specific at the moment, which explains why I've never seen it (even as a moderator who can see all the annotation types).

Comment: It's not actually SO-specific anymore. I suppose I should write that up.

Comment: I'm +1-ing this because I want 30ks to have the ability to edit locked questions.

Answer (score 16):

### Add an improved timeline.

I'm not a moderator on any site, but I know that moderators get a lot of extra information from a post's timeline that are not available. In particular, I would love to have direct links to review queues related to a particular post, rather than having to manually search in the history. I'm sure there are other tools there as well that I'm not aware of.

---

[@Shog9 said that this is basically a dead feature for regular users here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262678/why-is-there-no-link-to-timeline-of-the-post), but this is exactly the sort of information that would be a nice reward and could also help with moderation without feeling like a duty. It's nice to be able to see "oh, this low quality answer wasn't deleted because it was edited out of the queue, but it's still low quality". Or "I see a reopen vote here, but this question is awful, and I want to Leave Closed review it".

Comment: Related question: [Is there any general way to obtain the review ID or review summary for a certain review job without the 10 k tools?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248286/255554)

Comment: This is now pretty much implemented, I think - cf. the accepted answer in Wrzlprmft's link.

Answer (score 11):

My proposal is for MSE only, but maybe can be expanded later somehow to other sites.

MSE tends to get lots of programming questions, from people unaware of what this site is about, landing here in mysterious ways and thinking this is Stack Overflow.

I'd say it's at least 20 questions every day. Not much, but enough to make noise.

I would like that users with 30k reputation will have binding close vote under those conditions:

1. Close reason only *off-topic ⇒ "This question does not appear to be about the software that powers the Stack Exchange network"*.
2. Question has 0 or negative score.
3. OP (user who posted the question) does not have any reputation on the site, i.e. 1 reputation or 101 with association bonus. (Yes, this is not rare to see as well.)

If all of those are true, the close vote will be binding, and the question will be insta-closed.

Just for fun, recent example of what I'm talking about:

> [image]

Comment: [Programmers will be next in line for this feature](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7020/31260)

Comment: Surely this could apply as written to any meta e.g. MSO as well as MSE.

Comment: @RobertLongson On normal metas (like MSO), the 5 rep requirement to post takes care of most crap questions.

Comment: We could certainly use this (or something like this) @gnat.

Comment: @Robert also, in per site meta it's very rare to have such off topic questions as far as I can tell, I guess that not even one in a day.

Comment: How would you limit it to a particular custom close reason, though? That's the sticky part.

Comment: @Nathan leaving this up to the team... believe they can find a way. (It's not a custom reason, it's pre-defined in the system)

Answer (score 10):

#### Limited ability to see question bans on related SE sites.

---

***The Problem***:
Programmers frequently sees low quality questions that would have been asked on SO except that the asker has been question banned from SO.

***The Proposal***:
Allow 30k users the ability to see if a new poster is blocked on a related technology site where the question should have been asked.  To simplify things, this privilege could be limited to migration target sites.

An example:  `user31415` asks a low-quality question on Programmers that is clearly an implementation issue but needs work in order to meet SO's quality guidelines.  I should be able to click through to the user's profile to see if they are question banned on SO or not.

Why?  If I know the user is question banned on SO, I can leave a comment helping explain how to get out of being question banned.  If the user isn't question banned, then I can explain what needs to be done to improve the question so it can be migrated.

The whole point is to be able to tailor constructive feedback to the new user's actual situation.

Comment: I think this is too specific to SO/P.SE.

Comment: @Scimonster - As a mod on Engineering, I see similar cross-posting patterns with low quality questions.  Physics, EE, and others are common targets for cross-posts or "I was banned on XYZ.SE, so I'll go ask on ABC.SE instead."

Comment: @Scimonster Code Review would benefit from this as well.

Comment: This seems like a useful *moderator* privilege.

Comment: @Emrakul it would be helpful for mods, but remember that its often the high rep active users who are the first ones on to a question. Being able to say "this is wrong, and should have been posted on XYZ.SE instead" vs. "I see that you are rate limited / banned on XYZ.SE, and this question really doesn't fit here because its not in our help center / charter."  Giving good *correct* guidance earlier can help prevent users from being pushed from SE to SE in migrations and work to get users to better understand the site they have posted on.

Comment: They "Why?" part isn't convincing. The user's reason for asking a question at your site shouldn't be your concern. If the question is acceptable, fine. If it's not, close it. That's all.

Comment: @pizza - I appreciate your thoughts, but it is a very real issue for SO / Programmers and with other SE sites.  I would prefer to give accurate, constructive feedback to a user instead of seeing them get question banned on two sites instead.  There's anecdotal evidence of askers appreciating feedback on how to ask constructive questions and how to fix what they have already tried.  Likewise, there's plenty of evidence of bitter users who leave the community after getting banned at 2 sites.  A lot of their vitriol could have been prevented with correct, constructive feedback.

Comment: Should there be a review queue for question from users that have been baned elsewhere?

Answer (score 10):

Derived from [terdon's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252745/270345):

### Grant edit privileges to 30k users on *all* meta sites.

---

You cannot suggest edits on the normal meta sites. This is supposedly due to [low traffic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97371/270345). Even so, the content on meta is rarely technical, so expertise in the subject matter is not necessary for tidying up meta discussions. (Some) Visiting 30k users would be glad to tidy up posts they encounter. It is frustrating to see a grammatical, typographical or formatting flaw in an otherwise-great post, and as you reach to edit it … Nope, not a 2k user here? No thanks, we don't need your corrections.

One might consider this analogous to granting chat privileges based on your home site reputation, instead of your reputation on the one you're visiting.

Meta SE might be an exception, since you can suggest edits here.

Answer (score 10):

[Kevin B suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408420/exempt-edits-from-title-cannot-contain-for-high-rep-users?noredirect=1#comment849059_408420) that I add this here:

[Exempt edits from "Title cannot contain ..."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408420/exempt-edits-from-title-cannot-contain-for-high-rep-users) for 30k users.

The linked Meta.SO question has a fuller proposal and discussion.

Answer (score 9):

Give 30k users the ability to see Not An Answer flags, perhaps in a review queue. They already have the ability to delete answers at 20k, now let's give them the ability to quickly and easily see which answers they can spend these votes on. Ultimately, it could be possible for 30k users to completely handle Not An Answer flags, which should help the mod queue somewhat.

Comment: What about spam flags?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Spam flags are already handled automatically by the community. No moderator involvement.

Comment: How are spam flags handled by community then?

Comment: The vast majority of NAA-flagged answers is sent to the VLQ queue anyway, so this mostly already exists.

Answer (score 8):

### At 30K, extend the dupe hammer to tags in which I have a silver badge.

---

In the never-ending battle against dupes, we can enlist the help of more qualified people, defined as those who have acquired a silver badge in a tag along with a total of 30K rep.

For instance, I only have a silver badge in HTML, but I see no small number of posts that I would feel confident in unilaterally closing as dupes.

Comment: This actually might fit better [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240700/empowering-tag-badge-holders-part-ii-lets-look-at-silver)

Answer (score 6):

See (your) flag and review history for an arbitrary post.

Being able to see a more complete history of a post would allow trusted users to have a better idea of what the community sees at issue with the post and how to help direct either the poster or the community to a more productive outcome.

Being able to see if a post had:

- Flag

  - Counts for

    - VLQ flags
    - NAA flags
- Reviews

  - Links to the reviews (in progress and) completed on a given post

    - First post
    - Late answer
    - Close
    - Reopen
    - Low quality post
    - Triage and Help & Improvement (where enabled)

The 'see links to posts' is more of a "don't make this hard".  I have occasionally had need to hunt up the reopen review on a post.  So I go dig through my close votes to find where I voted on a question, and then I get a date, and then I tweak the URL of the reopen review queue history by 25s or 50s until I get into the range, and then I start searching for the post name.  Very tedious.  I am fortunate that this isn't SO or another site that generates scores of pages of reviews a day.

This would have some utility in finding out who is [who is sniffing glue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314661/what-is-it-i-dont-understand-about-the-very-low-quality-flag?lq=1#comment294208_314663) questions that sometimes show up on various meta sites.

The related bit here is that it would allow 30k users to better answer the questions about why certain things happened on meta and possibly reduce some of that load from mods who are currently the only ones with similar tools.

It would also allow 30k users a better insight into what the community feels needs to be done with a post and either fix it (given their more intimate familiarity with the workings of the site) or speed it on its way (poor quality negatively scored answer that has had NAA flags against it? - look at how the question can be made better so such answers aren't viable, or leave a comment about how to improve the answer, or make edits to improve the answer, or down vote and delete vote if that is the appropriate action).

Comment: You can already see all completed reviews through the timeline.

Answer (score 6):

#### Vote to lock/unlock posts

Users gain the privileges to close/reopen, protect/unprotect, and delete/undelete posts. It seems natural that the next privilege should be the ability to vote to lock/unlock posts. 30k users should have enough moderation experience to know when a question should be locked or unlocked, and if they use it wisely, it could help the site a lot.

Comment: I think we'd need to disallow locking/unlocking your *own* posts, though.  I've seen high-rep users ask mods to lock their posts because they're getting comments they don't like.  If the comments are not constructive they should be deleted instead; if the reason you don't like them is that they *challenge your answer* somehow, you shouldn't be able to shut that down.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding more privilege based on reputation, which at high number only reflects:

- How well the user gets accustomed to the system and gains reputation by answering (while there are users who have high reputation by posting mostly questions, I don't think they are going to have too many reputation)
- For most of the times, how many answers the user has posted, but tells nothing about the quality of the answers.
- How long the user has been spending on the site (relatively), without any indicator of the user's activity in improving the quality of the site

I think the new privilege should be based on badges or badges + reputation or even a number *beyond* the requirement to get a certain badge. The point is to target people who care and want to upkeep the quality of the site **and** have proven their capability to do so more tools and power to speed up the processes. We can also take meta participation into account, though how to quantify it is not yet clear at the moment.

For example, high number of edits and reviews (could be set higher than the requirement for badge), plus gold tag badge gives the user binding close vote for any vote types on questions in the tag (with the same rules as current implementation). Same idea can be applied for silver tag badge, with reduced power/close vote types.

Comment: Good idea, but I don't see how this is an answer to the question being asked here.

Comment: @Shog9: Basically, "scrap this idea of adding privilege for 30k and go in a different direction". Though I admit this answer doesn't provide any idea for the other direction.

Answer (score 2):

Create custom question filters for themselves for example

- Only show me questions with a specific tag and some keyword.
- Hide questions from people with less than N rep.
- Hide questions from people who's home site<sup>1</sup> is $OtherSESite e.g. SF or SO
- Hide questions with a [sometag](/questions/tagged/sometag) and a keyword.
- Some combinations of the above and other $stuff.

---

By the time you get to 30k anywhere (with the possible exception of SO) you're probably finding it hard to wade through all the questions to find something interesting to answer. You probably have some ideas on how you can help yourself but you don't have any way of easily achieving that. For example I believe SF would be more relevant to me if I could hide all the questions from SO users who have less than 10k rep (it could be 100k or it could be 2k) it doesn't mater - it's a start. Similarly anything tagged [dns](/questions/tagged/dns) containing the word `port` I really don't want to see.

---

For sites outside of SO 30k may be too high for this. SF has just 26 30k users far too many talented people fall by the wayside and for many of them wading through the crap to find an interesting question will be the cause.

<sup>1</sup> A home site is the site you have most rep e.g. for me SF.

Comment: Some (most actually) of these features are planned to be added for all users. See questions with updates on the front page design and question list design.

Comment: This is a good direction, and would definitely make 30k users feel special, but if they're going to work on better search, I think they should just do it for everybody.

Comment: @JoshCaswell http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232242/help-us-find-duplicates-efficiently

Answer (score 0):

#### Ability to make community wiki questions

My suggestion is to allow users at this level to be able to mark their own questions as community wiki, if they have at least 3 community wiki answers. This would make sure they have at least some experience with community wiki, and would know when to make a question community wiki.

Answer (score -1):

## More bounty freedom

I think its a good idea to give 30k users the ability to do more with bounties.  Some ideas are below. I think the privilege should consist of a combination of these. These changes only go for the bounties the users own themselves, of course.

---

**1.** When a bounty ends or is being awarded, they can add an extra bounty of the same value immediately to another answer. The question doesn't show up another week in the featured tab. So it's just an option when awarding the bounty.

*Advantages.* If there are two good answers, the awarder doesn't have to choose between those two or give one of the answers another, larger bounty.

---

**2.** Being able to split the bounty between multiple answers.

*Advantages.* If there are two good answers, the awarder doesn't have to choose between those two or give one of the answers another, larger bounty.

*Disadvantage.* The answerers get a smaller bounty than expected.

---

**3.** Being able to edit the bounty message (only once per bounty) with changes less than 5 characters.

*Advantages.* This small edit can only be used to correct spelling mistakes, and cannot be abused.

*Note:* Maybe it should be possible that they can also edit other person's bounty messages, maybe with approval of the bounty owner.

---

**4.** Being able to have more than three bounties.

*Advantages.* High-rep users usually ask high-level questions, so they might need bounties to get the question answered or to reward good answers. These users can be trusted to not abuse it for rep transfer and such things.

---

**5.** Set a superbounty. This bounty can have the values +250, +500 and +750. A superbounty can only be set on a question which has had at least one other bounty. These bounties will always show up on top of the featured tab. They last two weeks instead of one. It will also be orange instead of 
blue, to give it even more attention. I think it should be limited to one active superbounty per user.

*Advantages.* On the largest sites even bounty questions may drown sometimes. For example, on stack overflow there are 400 bounty questions. This makes sure the question really got the largest amount of attention possible.

---

**6.** Raise the bounty award when giving it to some answer.

*Advantages.* Sometimes an answer of unexpected elegance is given and the answerer deserves a greater bounty than the question originally had.

Comment: I'm good with everything except #3. If we allow editing the bounty message, we may as well let everyone do it, and there should be a grace period rather than a character limit.

Answer (score -3):

I think you could make a little shift of power from the elected moderators to the people who worked a lot for the rep.

I have two ideas:

1. allow them to see flag counts (i.e., they would know, which post/comment how many times was flagged). No more.

XOR

2. allow them to list the deleted posts, like the moderators.

Comment: 10kers can see deleted posts.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Although 10k users can see deleted posts, they can list and search only in their own. Only you can do anything with deleted posts (incl. unlimited search / list of them).

Comment: (Isn't XOR just *or* in English? (Not a rhetorical  question.))

Answer (score -3):

#### Allow them to migrate anything to anywhere, like the mods.

On this way, in the case of a new or small SE site, it would be easier to collect its initial user & content base, if they can earn the support of the 30k users of similar sites.

Comment: 30k reputation is a good sign that you know what's off-topic for your site, but not that you know what's on-topic for other sites.

Comment: @Mark The same problem exists also in the case of the mods. The logic is: expecting them to not going mad, just like it is expected also from the mods.

Comment: @peterh Honestly, yes, it *is* also a problem for mods.  That's why the moderator migration rates are honestly not all that great.  That's not a reason to give the privilege to more people likely to make the same mistakes.

Comment: @Servy I think not the mods migrating "too much" commit mistakes. The mistake is in the closed, inbreed communities rejecting imported content on cloudy, irrational reasons. This results that the mods don't migrate anything. The 30k users, not on the short leash of the mods, could work much more freely.

Comment: @peterh Thanks for proving my point for me that this would just result in people migrating lots of content that doesn't actually belong on the target sites.  The unrelated personal insults is just the cherry on top of that argument.

Comment: @Servy No. It is content what *belongs to these sites*, only our wonderful good old boys don't let in, because they are... well... maybe they've lost some crucial sense of their objectivity in their long SE experience.

Comment: @peterh You, who are not a member of those sites and who don't really know what does or doesn't belong there, think it belongs there.  But the people who actually actively contribute to the site and are the primary answerers there, think it doesn't belong there.  And you think forcing them to have the content that outsiders think belongs there but that the actual contributors there don't want is a good idea.  History has shown, time and time again, that that ends badly.  Entire sites have been literally removed as a result of this happening.

Comment: @Servy The whole migration system is a crap. The intention would be to **reuse the offtopic closed posts everywhere to build the initial content/user base of new SE sites**. The massive wall before this obvious idea is very well visible on your attitude.

Comment: @peterh And yet history has shown, time and time again, by doing what you propose and having the larger sites shoveling their crap onto newer smaller sites just *kills* those sites.  Those smaller sites get flooded with bad questions that they don't have the user base to deal with, so everyone just leaves.  This has happened plenty of times before.  It has *never* resulted in actually helping those target sites by bringing in good content on a large scale.

Comment: @Servy Offtopic closed questions, particularly if they are voted up, are not crap. If the target site itself can decide, what content they want there and what they won't, it would improve them. But honestly, why should I explain *you* that triviality? Why should I *campaign* by the SE to not kill their own sites and their own content? Why should I *campaign* against *your* senseless destructivity? It is the site of the SE, if they want stagnage, as they are stagnating since 2014, then it is their problem. Feel yourself well on the "stabilized" sites, ruled by "good old boys",

Answer (score -4):

### **An Avatar Border**

[image: This incredible mock-up of this complicated concept tool a whole 2 minutes for me to make]

A simple colored border around the avatar to highlight the user's high level of respect on individual SE site.  It could be given a unique color for each SE so that it doesn't just blend into the SE's background.

Answer (score -5):

Give them decisive undelete/reopen votes.

On this way, they could fix unfairly handled posts.

Comment: Sounds extremely dangerous.

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain Why?

Comment: That's still a dangerous privilege, even if it's only for 30k users.

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain I think the danger of a mistakenly reopened/undeleted post is far smaller than the danger of the falsely closed/deleted posts. Imagine also the felling what it creates. A clearly bad post will be surely end up as closed.

Answer (score -6):

### 3D Mode à la Stack Exchange Extreme!

Now with HTML5, we could have real 3D-mode built into the site. Many proposals focus on external presentation (blogs), moderation (which is really just tyranny of the elite), and other such features.

I would like a usable interface. Back in the 1990s, [Excite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excite) saw the value in this and created [**Excite Extreme!**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aw9x5us4ZM4). It was my favorite way to navigate the web. I'd like to be able to use this site in a similar fashion. Why does searching for `[php] + [mysql]` return to me an antiquated two-dimensional list when it can return a full fledged WebGL interface using [high-tech VR](https://mixedreality.mozilla.org/)?

Imagine when you search, if you could for instance hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> and find yourself perusing the results from a different dimension, or swimming through the answers. I would want to work towards that. That's the incentive I need to keep me active as a positive contributing member of this community.

[The future is here!](https://youtu.be/pBSR3DyobIY) Let's break linear chains and start the revolution.

Comment: Why do you need 30k rep for that? Why not just open it up to everyone? :)

Comment: ``/index.vrml``

Comment: @user134300: Wow, that's a blast from the past. I don't think I've even thought about VRML for a solid decade.

Answer (score -6):

Give them the ability to put a bounty to questions on the moment as they were asked.

<sub>Ordinary mortals can bounty a question just after 2 days. [Here Shog explains, why is it so.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306422/259412)</sub>

Comment: 30K users ask very few questions. Most of them got to 30K by answering.

Comment: @RobertLongson These don't need to be their own questions...

Comment: If I come across questions organically they're almost certainly going to be old enough to bounty anyway.

Comment: @RobertLongson Imagine the rush on a fresh, stellar question which is boosted also with a big bounty. Imagine the power in the hands capable to create such questions... and imagine, how wonderful is it, that it would not be a destructive power. These don't exist 2 days later. A 2 day old question is an oldie... around 20-30% of the upvotes arrives to the answers of such old posts.

Answer (score -22):

#### Social Network-ey features

Give 30k users a more customizable profile page.  Let them customize the CSS (maybe just offer a few templates), add a background image, etc.  Really Myspace it up.

Give 30k users the ability to post messages to their profile page.  Either short twitter-style messages, or longer blog-style posts.  Allow all users (30k or no) the ability to follow these feeds, offer both RSS and an SE mechanism that adds new posts to the follower's SE inbox.

Give 30k users the ability to directly message other 30k users.  This would provide a private message feature that crops up here on Meta.SE from time to time as a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Along with these, include filtering/ignoring functionality to grant these users control over who they communicate with and who follows them.

Comment: "Along with these, include filtering/ignoring functionality to grant these users control over who they communicate with and who follows them." This misses the point of SE. We're supposed to judge it on the content of the answer, not the user (unlike what our usercard may imply). Arguably, it's not very common that it happens, but that's the intent. Unless you are talking about PMs. Which a block user functionality would definitely be needed.

Comment: @justcool393 I'm talking purely about the social network functionality here.  Direct communication enables abuse and harassment, which means you need to grant users blocking/filtering tools.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, that would be important for any social functionality. I think the only thing I object to is the custom CSS, but I find it interesting how many people seem to dislike social networking features.

Comment: I really like the idea of custom css and posting messages on your profile. However, I completely object to allowing 30k users to be able to fully ignore a user.

Answer (score -54):

### FASTEST GUN SHIELD / TRIGGER VOTE RESET.

One of Stack Exchange's longest standing problems is the so-called "Fastest Gun" problem, where disproportionate weight is given to earlier answers at the expense of later, potentially more comprehensive answers.

The ultimate effect is that there's little or no point adding a new answer to an established question, even if you have a canonical answer that is arguably of vastly higher value.

I propose that 30K users can trigger a 'Vote Reset' on any question a) That they've answered and b) that is more than 3 months old, thus allowing a fresh ballot of answers.

(TO CLARIFY: The original posters would retain their rep from their original answers)

Comment: I'm sensing that people aren't liking this idea.

Comment: This sounds like something that could subject to abuse. Then we need a feature to counter that abuse. While there is benefit in this when maintaining popular old question, I think the drawbacks outweighs the benefit here.

Comment: @nhahtdh - If you abuse it, your answer (which you're basically saying "**this** is definitive" about) will get downvoted into hell.

Comment: @nhahtdh Abuse? That outrageous feature will utterly drive the voting and answering system ad absurdum. That is far from the mild word of "abuse", I guess. Every single use of that feature seems basically abuse. ;-)

Comment: @Richard: Looking at the ideas again, I think this is a poor solution for fastest gun problem. There are not going to be as many people looking at an old question, compared to when it is first posted. And when the votes are reset, people from the internet can't tell which answer is the "best" among all the answers.

Comment: @nhahtdh  - Huh? The whole point of the upvote/downvote system is to allow people from the Internet to pass judgement on the rightness of answers

Comment: In my experience, it is often worth taking a few minutes extra to improve your answer to get more votes. I don't see how a vote-reset would help here at all. I suggest you think this suggestion through once more, and/or give a better reason for why it would be a good feature. At the moment, I can't see anything positive with it.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg - Because currently there's no incentive to write an awesome new answer on an old question. If you do, it basically sits at the bottom and gathers dust, even when it's vastly superior to the existing answers.

Comment: @Richard Resetting the vote count on other answers would reduce the incentive to answer questions at all. Good luck in getting that "+100 score" answer badge now! Instead of having only one answer with low views and votes, now all of them have low votes. Instead, downvote and comment on the other answers and with your answer: Share, tweet and draw attention to it in a relevant chat-room in a nice way.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg - If your answer is superior, it'll get even more votes than it had before, plus you get extra rep from people re-voting for your old answer.

Comment: Re-voting giving rep is a bad idea IMO as it can lead to reputation cheats. And if my answer is superior but it's vote count is reset to zero, it will take a loooong time before it reaches it's previous vote count again. I wouldn't expect people to go back to previous questions and re-vote on the answers. Sorry, I really don't like this idea.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg  -I'm sensing that people aren't seeing the value.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 - It's not a popular answer, as you can see.

Comment: Nah. It's popular... just negatively popular!

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 - I remain convinced that this would be a good idea. It would encourage new, high quality answers to old questions.

Comment: Vote reset would abuse voting system. Why don't you propose "Default Sort change to Newest First for limited period of time after an answer is posted on old question".. This would serve your purpose without abusing the system.

Comment: Although this might not require user intervention unless you mutate the idea further. Or, simply request this feature as a new question.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 This (your default sort change) isn't a bad idea at all and might even work as its own feature request independent of the 30k reputation. It's far less invasive and abusive to the voting system and might already help to draw more necessary attention to the new answer.

Comment: It would just take one pissed off 30k user to go and wipe out a person's reputation. Let me just go to SO's top voted answers and basically append a -10000 vote to an answer.

Comment: @justcool393 - you misunderstand. They wouldn't lose their reputation when the vote gets reset. And your comment is a perfect example; why would you want to spend time creating an answer to a question that already has a massively upvoted answer, just so it can languish at the bottom?

Comment: Okay, it might not wipe out reputation, but it'll wipe out the 10k score that the answer accumulated. It just takes someone that's having a bad day to do this. Even if it was logged, it'd be more work for moderators. This can also make it harder for people that don't have as much reputation if an answer is good enough (or would just need a few edits).

Comment: I see your point, but I think the risks outweigh the benefits by a large margin.

Comment: @justcool393 - If an answer is good, it'll rise back up through the ranks. If it's poor, it'll sink. The idea that it should stay at the top merely because it's already got a high score is the very definition of the fastest gun problem.

Comment: But it will make legitimately good answers be unable to amass anywhere over a few hundred or possibly thousand points. There are around 1700 users on StackOverflow with over 30k, and around 200 more with 27k. I guess we'll have to disagree to disagree though.

Comment: @justcool393 - I'd be a little put out if I didn't get to 100 upvotes on an answer, but I'd be more upset if my *inferior* answer was permanently at the top of the pile, merely because it was older

Comment: @Richard You seem to assume that people who once voted on the answers of that question will just recover their votes on all the great old answers they once voted for instead of those votes just getting lost in oblivion. Not everyone is willing or attentive enough or even able to reconsider all his votes on a year old question just because it got a new answer from someone who thought *"screw all those other answers, mine is better anyway"* and expressed so by invalidating a hundred users' legitimate votes. Reputation or not is irrelevant to this problem.

Comment: @ChristianRau - I'm betting that someone who bothered to read the original question and bothered to vote on the original answers will be delighted to see that there's a new and (apparently) superior answer and will be more than happy to offer their vote again.

Comment: just add a random button to the "new/votes" tabs in the answers section of a question. make that the default.  somewhat /s

Comment: We need the fastest gun race, because askers want typically quick answers. (I did not vote to your post.)

Comment: @peterh - Sure, and there's nothing to stop people posting quickly. It's just that after a set period of time, if an experienced user feels that their answer is of higher value they can trigger the shield and reset the clock to allow the community to re-decide on which answer should be at the top of the pile.