# Can I get back original profile design?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

Can I get back to the original profile design? If not, can this be a feature?

Comment: I agree that it's gonna get some getting used to. But maybe, and I say maybe, you should be saying why you think that.

Comment: @MARamezani There's nothing I could add -- it's just that I don't want to get used to it and I want to stay with the old one. It is a suggestion post and we'll see what the moderators think, since I'm quite sure I'm not the only one here wanting this feature.

Comment: So far you *are* the only one. (13 minutes, 0 upvotes)

Comment: Anyway, once upon a time there was an envelope. It was removed. Feature request asking to bring it back got hundreds of upvotes. Guess what happened? :D

Comment: [Go propose it as a 30K privilege](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252690/what-privilege-should-30k-users-get)

Comment: *wondering if @Shog9 is being serious*

Comment: [The fate of the envelope](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MLgCL.png)

Comment: as Shakespear wrote, "thy new profile doth sucketh"

Comment: "I don't like change" is probably never going to be considered a good reason for anything, not here or anywhere else in life. Life is constantly changing, and dealing with change is one of life's most important skills.

Comment: The same people that moan about layout changes are the same people to complain when OTHER stuff isn't fixed because devs are spread thin.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. The current profile design will stay there until the developers change it up... Of course, there will be a big post telling people about it such as this one: [New profile pages are out - bugs and feedback master list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list)

And, no, it is unfortunately not a feature. The current design will stay this way until it changes...