# Can high-rep users be allowed to see meta notifications?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, meta, top-bar

As a moderator on HSM, I'm notified when a new meta post is started on HSM meta by a diamond on the top bar lighting up in blue. Here it is, not lit up.

[image]

<sup><sup>Don't judge the big bright orange 12; we're going through a site self-evaluation as of this screenshot.</sup></sup>

On other sites, I'm extremely active on meta, occasionally more so than on the main site itself. I check daily for new and/or active questions.

**Proposal**: Let users of sufficiently high rep see the same notifications as moderators. This would be quite handy for those active on meta.

One thing to consider, though, is that not all high-rep users are active on meta, and not all users active on meta have a lot of rep. I would guess there is a correlation, but I can't support that hypothesis.

---

I considered posting this on [What privilege should 30k users get?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252690/what-privilege-should-30k-users-get), but I don't think it should be limited to those with 30k rep.

Comment: I only see a benefit to sites with minimal meta traffic where a new meta post is a once every other day occurance.  High traffic sites will probably just annoy high rep users, especially those that don't want to participate in meta.  Can this be a user preference?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Good point. Could this be made optional, or would that be too complicated?

Comment: I doubt anyone would want this on a high traffic site. They turned off the notifications on MSO because it was far too noisy and distracting for mods.

Comment: @bluefeet I suppose this would be better on low-traffic sites, such as betas.

Comment: Instead of an amount of reputation, why not make this a function of "rep" on meta, which is otherwise useless? ... Anyway, that's a pretty good indicator of meta participation, if anything is.

Answer (score 12):

I've participated on several sites where this would have been handy.  Sure, it's not practical on huge sites like SO, but for the rest of us, this would help get more eyes on new posts sooner.  As a moderator I sometimes have to hold off answering because I want other members of the community to speak first on, say, a question of scope, because some might give undue weight to the diamond.  This means waiting for them to show up and do so.

This would serve another purpose too: on sites where people aren't in the habit of checking meta already, it acts as a prompt.  I've seen medium-high rep users who didn't seem to even *know* about meta.

Because this could be annoying (not everybody *wants* to participate in meta, and some sites get a lot of meta posts), this should be a per-site and per-user opt-in.  This could be added to the profile preferences:

[image: mockup of preference]

Answer (score 4):

[User script made by @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ](https://stackapps.com/a/6325/28139)

Get it at [Github](https://github.com/shu8/SE-Answers_scripts/raw/master/newMetaQuestionModAlert.user.js).

It gets the latest 5 questions posted on the per-site meta of the current site and adds a diamond to the top bar.

It is red if there are new questions, and white if there aren't.

It decides whether you've seen the questions by saving the latest question via `GM_setValue` - if the latest question via the API is equal to that, it will show white. So, basically once you click the button, it will go white the next time.

[image]

[image]

On sites without a meta, it will always look like the bottom gif above.