# Posting only once every 40 minutes even for experienced users?

Tags: discussion, rate-limiting

I have low rep on Physics & Woodworking, but not so on Stack Overflow.

I just tried to ask < 40 minute interval on those two and got hit with the [once-per-40-minute rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide/164900#164900):

[image]

I posted once on Woodworking, then ~5 minutes later tried to post on Physics, and was denied because of the 40 min rule. So apparently *the system looks cross-network to assess this rule*.

It seems the system is looking at my *lowest cross-network rep when applying this rule rather than highest rep*? What is the point of this very conservative approach? It would seem there is very little chance that a user with high rep on ANY site is likely to spam or abuse the lower-rep sites. And obviously this discourages participation across the network.

Furthermore, an improvement at least would be to warn the user ASAP so they aren't stuck with a nicely worded question in their browser window only which could be forgotten, lost, etc. As it is you only get the warning when you click `[Post Your Question]`.

Comment: This might actually be good [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252690/what-privilege-should-30k-users-get/318347).

Answer (score 5):

Presumably, the system looks at your rep on the site you're trying to post on (i.e. where you *currently* are), so if you have 124 or less rep on Physics, you get rate-limited there. You won't, however, if you ask there first and then ask another on Stack Overflow, since you have more than 125 on SO.

Comment: Thank you for this, it pointed out a detail that I didn't make clear in my question. (That wasn't my scenario. I posted once on woodworking, then ~5 minutes later tried to post on Physics, and was denied because of the 40 min rule.)

Comment: @DaveInCaz You have 124 on Physics so you can't ask there within 40 mins. This is what I supplied in my answer.

Comment: But I only tried to post on Physics ONCE. So it can't only be looking at the one site. And if it is looking at other sites, why not account for the user's higher rep on any of them?

Comment: @DaveInCaz I don't know about the reason behind the design, but the FAQ said explicitly "anywhere on the network", so your previous post on Woodworking limits you from asking soon on Physics.

Comment: Does the 125 rep include the association bonus, or is it like the 10 rep limit on protected questions, where the association bonus doesn't count?

Comment: @Olivia Rest assured, the association bonus counts towards the 125 rep requirement.