# Why is there a 40 minutes time limit for posting questions

Tags: discussion, questions, rate-limiting

This is a follow up question to this question:

[Posting only once every 40 minutes even for experienced users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318771/posting-only-once-every-40-minutes-even-for-experienced-users)

Why is there a limit for people under 124 rep? As long as there's a limit for number of questions per day, what does it matter if people ask them after 40 minutes or seconds?

Comment: To help ensure people invest meaningful effort into their questions before asking others to volunteer their time to help.

Answer (score 12):

It matters that everyone gets a fair shake and that one person cannot take all the finite attention of the answerers.

On top of that if you're asking questions that quickly you probably haven't thought them through.

- Have you really tried to answer them yourself?
- Are you sure that an answer to one of the other questions you're asking won't make this question moot?
- Have you really spent the time looking to see if this question has already been asked and answered?
- Are you sure you've written the question as clearly as possible.
- Have you really planned this? How have you ended up needing to ask so many questions so quickly. Your lack of forethought isn't really our problem.